# Output the Current Time

Tags: code-golf, date

## Challenge

You must output the current time continuously (until cancelled by an interrupt), once every second, by any of the following means:

- It must be in 24-hour or AM/PM format.

  - If it is the former, it must be spaced out with colons (i.e. 15:47:36).
  - If it is the latter, it must be spaced out with colons and have the AM/PM following (i.e. 3:47:36 PM)
- It may be pulled from the internet.
- It may be the system time.
- It must output any naturally accessible form of output which supports text that you choose.
- Output may have extra information aside of the time in it, but you *must* guarantee one, and only one, output of time per second.
- The continuous output must be a second apart - if you choose to wait until the second changes between outputs, that is fine. If you wait a second between each output, that is perfectly acceptable, despite the eventual loss of accuracy.

Since this is a catalog, languages created after this challenge are allowed to compete. Note that there must be an interpreter so the submission can be tested. It is allowed (and even encouraged) to write this interpreter yourself for a previously unimplemented language. Other than that, all the standard rules of [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) must be obeyed. Submissions in most languages will be scored in bytes in an appropriate preexisting encoding (usually UTF-8).

## Catalog

The Stack Snippet at the bottom of this post generates the catalog from the answers a) as a list of shortest solution per language and b) as an overall leaderboard.

To make sure that your answer shows up, please start your answer with a headline, using the following Markdown template:

```
## Language Name, N bytes
```

where `N` is the size of your submission. If you improve your score, you *can* keep old scores in the headline, by striking them through. For instance:

```
## Ruby, <s>104</s> <s>101</s> 96 bytes
```

If there you want to include multiple numbers in your header (e.g. because your score is the sum of two files or you want to list interpreter flag penalties separately), make sure that the actual score is the *last* number in the header:

```
## Perl, 43 + 2 (-p flag) = 45 bytes
```

You can also make the language name a link which will then show up in the snippet:

```
## [><>](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 121 bytes
```

```js
var QUESTION_ID=65020,OVERRIDE_USER=44713;function answersUrl(e){return"//api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/"+QUESTION_ID+"/answers?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function commentUrl(e,s){return"//api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/"+s.join(";")+"/comments?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+COMMENT_FILTER}function getAnswers(){jQuery.ajax({url:answersUrl(answer_page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){answers.push.apply(answers,e.items),answers_hash=[],answer_ids=[],e.items.forEach(function(e){e.comments=[];var s=+e.share_link.match(/\d+/);answer_ids.push(s),answers_hash[s]=e}),e.has_more||(more_answers=!1),comment_page=1,getComments()}})}function getComments(){jQuery.ajax({url:commentUrl(comment_page++,answer_ids),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){e.items.forEach(function(e){e.owner.user_id===OVERRIDE_USER&&answers_hash[e.post_id].comments.push(e)}),e.has_more?getComments():more_answers?getAnswers():process()}})}function getAuthorName(e){return e.owner.display_name}function process(){var e=[];answers.forEach(function(s){var r=s.body;s.comments.forEach(function(e){OVERRIDE_REG.test(e.body)&&(r="<h1>"+e.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG,"")+"</h1>")});var a=r.match(SCORE_REG);a&&e.push({user:getAuthorName(s),size:+a[2],language:a[1],link:s.share_link})}),e.sort(function(e,s){var r=e.size,a=s.size;return r-a});var s={},r=1,a=null,n=1;e.forEach(function(e){e.size!=a&&(n=r),a=e.size,++r;var t=jQuery("#answer-template").html();t=t.replace("{{PLACE}}",n+".").replace("{{NAME}}",e.user).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",e.language).replace("{{SIZE}}",e.size).replace("{{LINK}}",e.link),t=jQuery(t),jQuery("#answers").append(t);var o=e.language;/<a/.test(o)&&(o=jQuery(o).text()),s[o]=s[o]||{lang:e.language,user:e.user,size:e.size,link:e.link}});var t=[];for(var o in s)s.hasOwnProperty(o)&&t.push(s[o]);t.sort(function(e,s){return e.lang>s.lang?1:e.lang<s.lang?-1:0});for(var c=0;c<t.length;++c){var i=jQuery("#language-template").html(),o=t[c];i=i.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",o.lang).replace("{{NAME}}",o.user).replace("{{SIZE}}",o.size).replace("{{LINK}}",o.link),i=jQuery(i),jQuery("#languages").append(i)}}var ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe",COMMENT_FILTER="!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk",answers=[],answers_hash,answer_ids,answer_page=1,more_answers=!0,comment_page;getAnswers();var SCORE_REG=/<h\d>\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/,OVERRIDE_REG=/^Override\s*header:\s*/i;
```

```css
body{text-align:left!important}#answer-list,#language-list{padding:10px;float:left}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:5px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"> <div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table> </div><div id="language-list"> <h2>Winners by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table> </div><table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table>
```

Comment: Does "until cancelled by an interrupt" include closing the program or does it need a mechanism to stop the cycle coded into it?

Comment: @user81655 Yes, it can be any form of interrupt - don't worry about coding that bit.

Comment: Is it okay if your language's kernel automatically intercepts interrupts to show a debug menu?

Comment: @LegionMammal978 Absolutely fine. Extra output doesn't really matter, as long as the program at some point continuously outputs time.

Comment: @VoteToClose Does that mean my answer doesn't actually need the `substring` call?

Comment: @SuperJedi224 Absolutely correct.

Comment: Also, if it is in fact allowed to print more than just the current time, you should explicitly say so in the question.

Comment: Shall there be a tag [tag:catalog] for "Since this is a catalog, languages created after this challenge are allowed to compete."?

Comment: @Vi. http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/6961/should-there-be-a-catalog-tag-e-g-shortest-in-every-language

Comment: Are we allowed to display something like `01:47:2` for `01:47:02`?

Comment: @ThomasKwa I don't _really_ see a problem with it, as it is human-readable as a time.

Comment: From my Snap! answer, do I have to keep the wait 1 sec block? It's going to be still like 9:21:8...9:21:9... because unlike most other languages it doesn't keep whatever it said before.

Comment: @ev3commander If it's only one visible output per second, then that should be fine.

Comment: Looking at your watch: 0 bytes ಠ_ಠ

Comment: May there be spaces between the parts and the colons? `12 : 23 : 34`

Comment: @NBZ Yes, that's fine.

Comment: **Warning:** All `sleep 1` based answer break rule 5: *you must guarantee one, and only one, output of time per second.* !!

Comment: F. Hauri: How so? Rule 6 says "If you wait a second between each output, that is fine as well."

Comment: @VoteToClose Can I wait a second *before* the first output?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer I don't see a reason to disallow it.

Comment: @YetiCGN in single threaded solutions sleep needs to be tuned to compensate for the time elapsed looping and printing, else one of the printout valies will be skipped sooner or later.  therefor breaking "must be one second apart"  a "solution" that outpute 1000001 microseconds apart is not compliant so far as I can tell.

Comment: @Jasen Please read the sixth rule, which provides an exception to that.

Comment: rules six does not say "you may ignore the description and rule five and do this instead" it only says must...

Comment: @Jasen No, but the meaning of "that is fine" implies that the wait option is still valid, regardless of the eventual time loss. I have clarified this for you.

Comment: the time of the first incorrect output is random therefore, program only has to output once! ???

Answer (score 55):

## Minecraft 1.8.7, 7 + 8 = 15 [blytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7397/44713) (bytes + blocks)

Only one command block involved:

```
xp 1 @p
```

Output goes to the client console like so:

[image: times]

As part of the normal output.

This is the system:

[image: the system]

`xp` gives a specified amount of experience to a specified player with the syntax `xp <amount> <player>`. I'm pretty sure this is the smallest command that has singular output that I can get, now.

Comment: Doesn't this solution also depend on the existence of the repeaters and their timings? That would add more bytes.

Comment: @LegionMammal978 I accounted for that - 12 (bytes of code) + 8 (blocks used).

Comment: Don't say "19 bytes" because you didn't measure your answer size in bytes.

Comment: @feersum [There's a reason for me saying bytes, trust me.](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/7397/44713) This is the _closest thing to a consensus_ for MC as of now.

Comment: You can use the deprecated number codes can't you?

Comment: Use this scoring system if you want, 19 whatevers, but it isn't 19 bytes, because there is no previously defined encoding that allows you to store this solution in a 19-byte file.

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ I'd have to wrap it in JSON, I believe. Unless I used 1.6, but that's practically another language.

Comment: @VoteToClose Does an error message show up on both sides? (Also, for reference, the GZIP'ped schematic is 211 bytes long.)

Comment: @LegionMammal978 What do you mean by error message? (I'm using the consensus byte count. :P Although I am interested in how you get the schematic...?)

Comment: @VoteToClose It should produce an error message when given an invalid command such as `a`, and I was wondering if this showed up on both the server and client. I can't use MC right now, so I was wondering if you could test it. I hand-wrote the 256-byte schematic, then used `gzip -n9` on it. The new `tp` version is 206 bytes long.

Comment: @LegionMammal978 Error does not go to client console. Also, I just found a shorter way with `xp 1 @p`.

Comment: @VoteToClose If the error doesn't go to the client, then you can use its timestamp!

Comment: @LegionMammal978 The error is only put out to the command block timestamp, which is only accessible by clicking it. Don't think it _really_ counts as continuous output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32241/discussion-between-legionmammal978-and-votetoclose).

Comment: Or, to give you much more experience, do `xp 9 @p`.

Comment: @ev3commander Eh. Who needs xp, anyways?

Comment: Couldn't you use `say a`?  I am 99% sure that only puts one thing in the log.  (It says `a` in the chat).

Comment: @Pokechu22 It puts a command output AND a chat output, so no

Comment: is that the smallest redstone creation you can make

Comment: @ev3commander Couldn't find another way to delay a second. :P

Comment: Use 1.9/1.10  repeating and chain command blocks. You can golf furthur than this with them .

Comment: @GLASSIC I don't think I can - I need that second delay, and to use a repeating command block querying for a second of change in daytime would take more bytes than it's worth.

Comment: Why not 6 block timer? Why not `me .`?

Answer (score 19):

## JavaScript, 32 bytes

```
setInterval("alert(Date())",1e3)
```

Uses the fact that [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) evaluates code. This is not recommended, but when was that a concern in code golf?

`Date()` returns the current time and date in a format like this (may vary per system).

```
 Wed Jul 28 1993 14:39:07 GMT-0600 (PDT)
```

Comment: Would `setInterval(alert,1e3,Date())` work instead?

Comment: @ETHproductions It always shows the same time for me

Comment: @ETHproductions in your example `Date()` will only be evaluated once when you create the interval

Answer (score 16):

## [Snap](https://snap.berkeley.edu/snap/#open:http://snap.berkeley.edu/snapsource/tools.xml), <s>8</s> <s>7</s> 6 blocks

[image]
<sub>(source: [cubeupload.com](https://i.cubeupload.com/TpGafK.jpg))</sub>
(Yes, I changed it in MS Paint because I was too lazy to make another screenshot. So what? At least it's readable.)
click the script to run

24-hour clock.

Comment: I always love graphical programming languages. :D +1

Comment: oh hey ev3! I know you from Snap/Scratch forums :P why do you need Snap instead of Scratch, exactly?

Comment: @anOKsquirrel Because I don't need to nest all those join blocks.

Comment: Shouldn't that read `9:21:08`?

Comment: @Luke As shown by the TI-BASIC answer, the time without the leading zero in an output is fine. It is human readable and clear what the time is.

Comment: That image gives me a 404. It would be preferable to upload essential images to SE's imgur account, which should never be deleted.

Comment: It works fine for me.

Comment: Using 'MS Paint' should disqualify anyone at anytime.

Comment: Oh, ok, so scratch counts as a programming language as well?

Answer (score 16):

### sh (+ watch), 11 bytes

Script:

```
watch -n1 .
```

(no trailing newline)

Output:

```
Every 1,0s: . (SPACES) Sat Nov 28 19:07:51 2015
```

The amount of spaces depends on the terminal width.

Tested on Debian8 and NetBSD7.

Comment: Right tool for the job, +1

Comment: Wait, does this count as a programming language? Can you give me a link to an interpreter?

Comment: @VoteToClose `watch` is a coreutil. The real language is bash/sh.

Comment: So... shouldn't this be `Bash (distribution)`, not `watch`? @Doorknob

Comment: According to `apt-file` watch is in package `procps`. I'll change the language to `sh`.

Comment: Hmm You have to use `-p` switch to not break the rule *you must guarantee one, and only one, output of time per second.*!!

Comment: watch is a coreutil, but only code written is `-pn1 .`

Answer (score 11):

### Python 2, 47 bytes

```py
from time import*
while[sleep(1)]:print ctime()
```

No online link because ideone times out (huehuehue) before printing anything.

Thanks to @xsot for the `while[sleep(1)]` trick and the `ctime` trick.

Prints out the current date and time like so: `Fri Nov 27 21:23:02 2015`

Comment: /me claps slowly at the pun. Very funny Mego. ;D

Comment: I've posted [your solution for Python 3](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/65374/1004)

Comment: `sleep 1` based answer break rule 5: *you must guarantee one, and only one, output of time per second.*

Comment: @F.Hauri `sleep 1` causes the current thread to sleep for exactly one second. It complies with the rules.

Comment: @Mego No: If you sleep exactly 1 second between each operation of printing system time, If printing time take only 1 µs, You will miss 1 output every million of sec.

Comment: @F.Hauri It's more likely that something else beyond the program's control (like exhaustion of resources, a crash/reboot, cosmic rays, etc.) will happen that disrupts the program's execution in the 11.5 days of continuous running that it would take for a 1-microsecond delay for printing to build up to missing a second.

Comment: Printing time could take a lot more than just 1µs! Anyway you're wrong: `sleep 1` break rule 5.

Comment: @F.Hauri Considering that the challenge author himself uses the equivalent of `sleep(1)` in both [his AppleScript solution](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/66116/45941) and [his Vitsy+bash solution](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/66114/45941), it's clearly acceptable.

Comment: I disagree. if it was acceptable he would have said approximately.

Answer (score 9):

## Javascript ES6, 43 39 bytes

```
setInterval(_=>console.log(Date()),1e3)
```

Works with my current time settings (which have not been changed for some time, thank you), at least.

4 bytes saved by Conor O'Brien.

Comment: alert is shorter?

Comment: @Maltysen I think in many browsers you have to close one alert window in order to see the next one.

Comment: @Maltysen I tried it, messes up the interval somehow

Comment: You don't need `.toTimeString()` in Chrome and FF.

Comment: I think you can replace `new Date()` with `Date()`

Answer (score 8):

## Perl, Command Line, 24 bytes

```perl
sleep(say)while$_=gmtime
```

This must be run from the command line, as `perl -E'sleep(say)while$_=gmtime'` (on windows, use double quotes instead). The date will be output along with the time, which [seems to be allowed](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/65022).

---

### Perl, 25 bytes

```perl
sleep print$/.gmtime;do$0
```

In a scalar context, `gmtime` will return a string similar to `Sat Nov 28 10:23:05 2015`. The result from `print`, always 1, is used as the parameter for `sleep`. `do$0` is used to execute the script again, after the timer has finished.

Comment: As evidenced by @VoteToClose's [AppleScript solution](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65020/output-the-current-time/65022#65022) and [comment](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65020/output-the-current-time/65032#comment157287_65020), you do not need to extract the time.

Comment: Another 24-byte solution: `{sleep say~~gmtime;redo}`.

Comment: `sleep 1` based answer break rule 5: *you must guarantee one, and only one, output of time per second*.

Comment: @F.Hauri the rule was added after this post was made.

Answer (score 8):

## [Arcyóu](https://github.com/nazek42/arcyou), 27 bytes

```
(@ t(pn(zz 1)(p(st %H:%M:%S
```

I had to kludge together two new functions for this challenge, `zz` and `st`.

`pn`: Exactly like Lisp's `progn`.

`zz`: Direct link to Python's `time.sleep`.

`st`: Direct link to Python's `time.strftime`.

Normally, quotes would be necessary around the format string, but since there are no spaces, it's parsed as a symbol. The interpreter evaluates undefined symbols as themselves, so we get a string.

Comment: I would up vote, but I don't have any votes left. +1 ;c And nice updates. :D

Answer (score 7):

## Bash, <s>51</s> <s>31</s> <s>24</s> <s>21</s>  20 bytes

Thanks to @quartata for some very helpful comments. Thank you @Dennis for clarifications and for chopping off even more bytes. Thank you @VoteToClose for clarifying the rules (which apparently I am bad at reading) further reducing the bytes.

`date`  displays the the full date with a 24 hour clock. `sleep 1` sleeps for a second. `exec $0` loops the script infinitely.

```
date;sleep 1;exec $0
```

Comment: You don't need the shebang.

Comment: Also, I think you can replace the `true` with the `sleep 1` since `sleep` returns a `1`.

Comment: `date +%T;sleep 1;exec $0` is a bit shorter. @quartata Nitpicking: `sleep` has exit code zero, which is why `while` continues.

Comment: Oh I'm an idiot

Comment: You don't need to cut the string down, it can have extraneous output. c: Your code now becomes `date;sleep 1;exec $0`.

Comment: You don't need the space after `date`, so this is only 20 bytes.

Comment: some seconds wil be missed if you wait long enough.

Answer (score 6):

## Befunge 98, 53 bytes

```
 v
v>"EMIT"4(>H.8,':,M.8,':,S:.8,d,
>:S-    !!k^
```

Notes:

1. This program does not zero-pad the numbers it prints.
2. This program prints a space and then a backspace character after every number, as the `.` command prints an implicit space at the end.
3. The size of the stack in this program grows every second, and thus it will eventually run out of memory.
4. This program will overwrite the previous time when it prints a new one. To make it print each time on a new line, change the `d` on the first line to an `a`

Comment: Why is the "TIME" string necessary? Is there some way it's grabbing it? (I didn't know about this)

Comment: The `"EMIT"4(` at the beginning of the program is telling the interpreter to load the `TIME` fingerprint, which enables the `H`,`M`, and `S` instructions. (No, it doesn't emit the number 4).

Comment: That is _awesome_. I never even thought that many esolangs would do this, +1.

Comment: @VoteToClose Befunge 98 even has an instruction to execute an arbritrary program popped from the stack.

Comment: _runs off to learn this language_ Excuse me...

Answer (score 6):

### mIRC 7.49 <s>20</s> 16 Bytes

```
/timer 0 1 $time
```

Comment: Where can we test this?

Comment: You have to download mIRC it's a shareware IRC client. You can download it from: http://www.mirc.com/ also since the answer above makes use of `say` you will need to connect to a server and then join a channel. other wise you would use `echo` instead of `say`. mIRC has it's own scripting language mSL(mIRC scripting language)

Answer (score 5):

## PHP, 37 bytes

```
<?=date('G:i:s');header('refresh:1');
```

Outputs the formatted server time and sets the page to refresh every second.

Of course, it depends on your internet connection and how fast-repsonding your server is :)

[Demo](http://justachat.freevar.com/realtime.php)

[image]

Comment: Nope, no refreshing : `Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent `

Comment: @Martijn I have no idea what you can mess with, because it works for me :)

Comment: I'll remove the downvote as benefit of the doubt, but this works exactly once for me. Tried on two different regular servers.

Comment: Depends on whether you have output buffering turned on.

Comment: `<?=header('refresh:1').date('G:i:s');` should work with either output bffering setting.

Answer (score 5):

## [Jolf](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Jolf), <s>14</s> <s>8</s> 7 bytes

<sup><sup>Crossed out 14 is a striked 1? Naw, it will never catch on ;)</sup></sup>

[Try it here!](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#code=VGFEI2B-Mg) Click run, do not click on anything else ^_^ the page is highly... explosive. Yes. Fixed output system with update.

```
TaD#`~2
```

(I added some constants, and `~1` to `~4` are powers of `10`.)

### Explanation

```
setInterval("alert(Date())",1000);
     T         a      D#   ` ~2
```

Comment: Someone should create YAJSGV (Yet Another JavaScript Golfing Variant).

Comment: This seems to print a lot more than just the time.

Comment: @Dennis I assumed that was fine as per [other](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/65036/31957) [solutions](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/65026/31957)

Comment: My bad, I had only read yours and the Bash answer.

Comment: @Dennis Not a problem ^_^

Comment: Doesn't print once per second.

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ This doesn't guarantee output once per second, as neglecting to click the 'okay' button doesn't let it continue.

Comment: @VoteToClose okay; simple fix by changing to console logging. Will do once not on mobile

Comment: @intrepidcoder So far there are at least 3

Comment: @NeilSmithline See revisions.

Comment: @BlockCoder1392 [There is function golf](http://schas002.github.io/js-function-golf).

Answer (score 5):

### AutoHotkey, 50 bytes

```
x::Send,% a!=A_Sec? A_Hour ":" A_Min ":" a:=A_Sec:
```

Notes:

1. Requires you to hold <kbd>x</kbd> for continuous output.
2. Remove your finger from <kbd>x</kbd> to interrupt and end the output.
3. Output is in 24-hour format.

Comment: You could, for a few extra bytes, put that in a tooltip so it doesn't require the user to hold `x`.

Answer (score 5):

## C (on Linux x64), <s>179</s> <s>177</s> <s>175</s> <s>168</s> 159 bytes

```
#include<time.h>
#include<sys/time.h>
main(){struct timeval a;char b[9];for(;;){gettimeofday(&a,0);strftime(b,9,"%T",localtime(&a.tv_sec));puts(b);sleep(1);}}
```

Ungolfed:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
main(){
  struct timeval a;
  char b[9];
  for(;;){
    gettimeofday(&a, 0);
    strftime(b, 9, "%T",localtime(&a.tv_sec));
    puts(b);
    sleep(1);
  }
}
```

Only tested on, and likely only functions on, linux x64 (x32 might work, but other platforms probably won't).

The main difference between this program and the other posted C program is the use of linux-exclusive function calls, which, while terrible practice for real software, saves quite a few bytes...if you ignore all the compiler warnings.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Unless I'm mistaken, I believe you can remove the space between `#include` and `<...>`. Also, can you use `1e6` instead of `1000000`?

Comment: @VoteToClose You were right about the spaces in the `#include`s. It doesn't look like usleep() accepts 1e6, though - based on how fast it starts spitting out timestamps it just interprets it as 1.

Comment: ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ I don't really know C, either. I'll let the professionals at that. Welcome again, have an up vote. :D

Comment: Ah, another thing - you don't have to cut the string for just the time, so you can just output the entire date time, provided it has the time string required in it.

Comment: @VoteToClose It's actually shorter not to. The gettimeofday() syscall doesn't actually return the time of day - as far as I can tell it returns the length of time since the epoch (1/1/1970). strftime() turns that into a readable timestamp based on the system time. This is the shortest I can think to get it while only using C and syscalls.

Comment: Huh. Well done, then, +1.

Comment: I guess you can replace the `NULL` BY `0`, saving 3 more. Try that out!

Comment: You can use `%T` as the format spec in `strftime`.

Answer (score 5):

## [Dyalog APL](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>27 18</s> 16 bytes

```
':',¨⎕TS⋄→≢⎕DL 1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKM9JDM39b@6lbrOoRWP@qaGBD/qbnnUNulR5yIgz8VHwRCk5j9IEQA)

`⎕TS` Y M D h m s t
`':',¨` prepend : to each
`⋄` new statement
`⎕DL 1` wait a second and return actual waited time; 1.0something seconds
`≢` tally the actual waited time, giving 1
`→` go to line (1 = this line)

Answer (score 4):

### Powershell, 19 bytes

```
for(){date;sleep 1}
```

Comment: As it's since been pointed out that output merely needs to include the hh:mm:ss you can reduce to `for(){date;sleep 1}`

Answer (score 4):

### [Perl 6](http://perl6.org), 29 bytes

The *right* way to do this:

```perl6
Supply.interval(1).tap: -> $ {
  say join ':',.hour,.minute,.whole-second given DateTime.now
}
await Promise.new; # halt this thread indefinitely
```

```
22:21:58
22:21:59
22:22:0
22:22:1
22:22:2
…
```

The golfed version

```perl6
loop {sleep say join ':',now.polymod(1,60,60,24)[3…1]} # 56 bytes
```

```
3:59:26
3:59:27
3:59:28
3:59:29
…
```

Since the output doesn't have to be restricted to just the time, I can make it quite a bit shorter.

```perl6
loop {sleep say DateTime.now} # 29 bytes
```

```
2015-11-27T22:18:10-06:00
2015-11-27T22:18:11-06:00
2015-11-27T22:18:12-06:00
2015-11-27T22:18:13-06:00
…
```

Answer (score 4):

### R, 38 bytes

```
repeat{Sys.sleep(1);print(Sys.time())}
```

This outputs the current time in the following format:

```
[1] "2015-11-28 07:34:01 CET"
```

Answer (score 4):

## VBA,  69 Bytes

Getting the Time is easy, `now()` Only outputting every 1 second.... MUCH more verbose.

This is the "Right" way of waiting 1 second in VBA. ***78 Bytes***

```
Sub a():Debug.Print Now():Application.Wait Now()+TimeValue("0:0:1"):a:End Sub
```

Or if you want to Cut some Corners and only being right 86% of  the time is good enough ***63 Bytes*** 
*adding one SigFig take you to 95% accurate and a third will get you to 99.36%*

```
Sub a():Debug.Print Now():Application.Wait Now()+1e-5:a:End Sub
```

If you want to get the above method to 100% then you need ***69 Bytes*** `(1/86400)`

```
Sub a():Debug.Print Now():Application.Wait Now()+(1/86400):a:End Sub
```

All of these methods would stumble on a leap second Beacuse they do not wait for 1 second, But wait untill 1 second. At midnight when the clocks fall back an hour this clock will stop for 1 hour and then pick up where it left off.

VBA does allow for the Sleep Method but your byte couter is Ruined. ***97 Bytes***

```
Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal k as Long)
Sub a():Debug.Print Now():Sleep(1e3):a:End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

## AppleScript, <s>51</s> 35 bytes

```
repeat
log current date
delay 1
end
```

Pretty dang obvious. Prints the current date, which contains the time, delays a second, then continues.

Comment: So wait, is it allowed to print out the current date as well as the time?

Comment: @quartata Yes, any concatenation with the time, as long as the time is continuously output and _guaranteed_ to be output, is fine.

Comment: delay 1 does what? pause for 1000000000 ns?

Comment: @Jasen That's correct.

Answer (score 3):

### Perl, <strike>99</strike> <strike>81</strike> <strike>75</strike> <strike>51</strike> <strike>40</strike> <strike>36</strike> <strike>29</strike> 27 bytes

```
sleep(print gmtime.$/);do$0
```

Comment: You can shorten it by using `gmtime` instead of `localtime`.

Comment: Also `printf"%02d:%02d:%02d\n",(gmtime)[2,1,0]`

Comment: `gmtime."\n"` will force a scalar context.

Comment: You should almost never need to do `."\n"` in golf: use `.$/` to save 2 bytes. At the very least, use a literal newline instead of `\n` to save 1 byte.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript, <s>47</s> <s>38</s> 35 bytes

```js
for(p=1;t=Date();p=t)t!=p&&alert(t)
```

### Explanation

Continuously checks if the time has changed then `alert`s if it has.

```js
for(
  p=1;
  t=Date();
  p=t
)
  t!=p
    &&alert(t)
```

Comment: You don't have to just get the time string. ;D As long as it's in there somewhere.

Comment: @VoteToClose Oh true!

Comment: Don't think you need the `+""`, as without `new`, `Date()` returns a string.

Comment: @ETHproductions Ah, yes that was left there from when it used `new`. Thanks for catching that!

Answer (score 3):

## Java, <s>300</s> <s>166</s> <s>137</s> <s>125</s> 124 bytes

<s>Nearly</s> More than halved thanks to VoteToClose, Paülo Ebermann and janschweizer!

```java
interface A{static void main(String[]a)throws Exception{for(;;Thread.sleep(1000))System.out.println(new java.util.Date());}}
```

Ungolfed:

```java
interface A {
    static void main(String[] a) throws Exception {
        for (;; Thread.sleep(1000)) System.out.println(new java.util.Date());
    }
}
```

Comment: @VoteToClose Now it *is* Java.

Comment: Simplify your imports: `java.util.*` instead of the two `java.util` imports, `java.text.*` for the same reasoning. Use `for(;;)` for infinite loops. Use `String[]a` in the main declaration. Use `interface A{static void main(...`, as this will shorten it even more. You can use `Exception` over `InterruptedException`, and you can replace `ex` with `e`. You can also remove all text inside the catch, as this does nothing anyways.

Comment: You will need Java 8 for the interface trick. ;)

Comment: @VoteToClose Thank you so much! I just did a tiny bit of googling and got this to compile so I'll add those! I do have Java8 :)

Comment: Yeah, the interface thing is a little wacky - I have no idea why Java would let that be a thing, considering that interfaces are _specifically designed_ to be unrunnable.

Comment: Two things: you need to change the time string to "HH:mm:ss" - as of now, you're formatting "Hour:Month:Second". Also, since you're using a loop, you can get rid of the `DateFormat` and `Calendar` variables declarations all together. You replace the contents of the for loop with `System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()));try{Thread.sleep(1000);}catch(Exception e){}`.

Comment: All of the things I just suggested, wrapped up: `import java.util.*;import java.text.*;interface A{static void main(String[]a){for(;;){System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()));try{Thread.sleep(1000);}catch(Exception e){}}}}`

Comment: I think you don't need the calendar, you can directly use `new Date()` for the current time.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann Fixed, thanks!

Comment: `throws Exception` is shorter than a try/catch

Comment: Also, your import of java.text is not needed anymore.

Comment: Some more bytes to golf: 1. Save 3: Move `Thread.sleep(1000)` into for-loop - killing off two brackets { } and one semikolon ; 2. kill the import of java.util and write `new java.util.Date()` instead - saving another 9: `interface S{static void main(String[] a)throws Exception{for(;;Thread.sleep(1000))System.out.println(new java.util.Date());}}`

Comment: @janschweizer [???](https://repl.it/B4gd/0)

Comment: Because of the brackets `[]`, you can save a byte by removing the space in the parameter of `main`, i.e. `main(String[]a)`.

Comment: @rgettman duh, I knew that but I didn't see it, thanks

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/Japt), 8 bytes

**Japt** is a shortened version of **Ja**vaScri**pt**.

```
1e3i@OpÐ
```

[Test it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=master&code=MWUzaUBPcNA=&input=)

#### How it works

```
1e3i@       // Repeat this function every 1e3 milliseconds:
     OpÐ    //  Output new Date(), followed by a newline.
```

Note that this also outputs a seemingly random integer when the code is run. To get rid of this, use this code:

```
1e3i@OpÐ};P
```

On my computer, the time is formatted as `2015-11-28T16:00:18.013Z`. If you don't like that, try this code instead:

```
1e3i@OpÐ s8};P
```

Which will lovingly print your time in the format `11:00:18 AM`.

Answer (score 3):

## Haskell, <s>98</s> <s>96</s> 85 bytes

```
import GHC.Conc
import Data.Time
m@main=getCurrentTime>>=print>>threadDelay(10^6)>>m
```

Alternate version using do notation:

```
main = do
  time <- getCurrentTime
  print time
  threadDelay 1000000
  main
```

Gets the current time with `getCurrentTime` from the `Data.Time` library, then pipes it into `print`, waits 1,000,000 microseconds (1 second) and calls itself.

Thanks to nimi and Mauris!

Comment: `m@main=...>>m` is always shorter than `main=...>>main`

Comment: Also, since `threadDelay` is GHC-specific anyway, you could import it from  [`GHC.Conc`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/GHC-Conc.html#v:threadDelay)

Answer (score 3):

## Batch - 34 <s>40</s> bytes

I love built-in variables:

```
:A                    //Set label A
echo %time%           //Print the time in 24 hour format
timeout 1    //Wait 1 second (thanks DavidPostill)
goto A                //Jump back to A and repeat
```

<sub>There definitely needs to be some `sleep` command in Batch anytime soon.</sub>

Comment: No builtin sleep but there is [timeout](http://ss64.com/nt/timeout.html). You can replace the `ping ...` with `timeout 1`. Also the clock isn't very accurate when using `ping`. It's better with `timeout` ;)

Comment: @DavidPostill thanks for the tip, I never knew there was such a command in Windows. :)

Comment: @GiantTree You're very welcome ;)

Comment: Golf: remove `:A` and replace `goto A` with `%0`

Answer (score 3):

## , 13 chars / 25 bytes

```
Ĥ⇀ôᶁ⬮+⬬),1)
```

<kbd>[Try it here(Firefox only).](http://molarmanful.github.io/ESMin/interpreter.html?eval=false&input=&code=%C4%A4%E2%87%80%C3%B4%E1%B6%81%E2%AC%AE%2B%E2%AC%AC%29%2C1%F0%9D%95%9C%29)</kbd>

This is surprisingly readable.

Comment: When you say "surprisingly readable", you know you're dealing with an amusing language. +1

Answer (score 3):

## Dyalog APL, 36 bytes

Not very short this time.

```
{⎕←1↓∊'⊂:⊃,ZI2'⎕FMT 3↑3↓⎕TS⋄∇⎕DL 1}1
```

This outputs 24-hour time, i.e.:

```
14:37:44
14:37:45
14:37:46
...
```

Explanation:

- `{`...`}1`: define a function and call it (the argument is ignored, but we need the function in order to call it recursively)

  - `⎕TS`: a system function that returns the current date and time, in the format *year - month - day - hour - minute - second - millisecond*. (`⎕TS` = **t**ime**s**tamp)
  - `3↑3↓`: drop the first 3 items (i.e. year - month - day) and then take the first 3 items that are left (hour - minute - second).
  - `'⊂:⊃,ZI2'⎕FMT`: format each number as a two-digit integer (`I2`) with leading zeroes (`Z`), prefixed by a colon (`⊂:⊃`). (This results in a matrix.)
  - `∊`: Get all the elements in the matrix, in row order. (This gives a vector, in this case a string.)
  - `1↓`: drop the first character (which is an extra `:`)
  - `⎕←`: output it
  - `⎕DL 1`: then wait one second (`⎕DL` = **d**e**l**ay)
  - `∇`: call the function recursively

Comment: `{⎕←1↓∊':',¨⍕¨3↑3↓⎕TS⋄∇⎕DL 1}1` for 28 bytes, is enough [as per OP](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65020/output-the-current-time?page=1&tab=votes#comment157414_65020).

Comment: The new rules allow garbage output and random spaces, so you can get rid of a lot.

Answer (score 3):

## QBasic, 18 bytes

```
?TIME$
SLEEP 1
RUN
```

Answer (score 3):

### Python 3, 99 Bytes

Apologies if it formats the code weird, doing this from an ipad. (dont ask). I know this code is big considering some of the other answers, but I didn't see a python one yet so I wanted to add it in.

```
import time
import datetime
while(True):
 print(datetime.datetime.now().time())
 time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: You can replace `True` with `1`, and if you put the `print` and `sleep` lines on the same line as the `while` (separated with a semicolon) it saves you the whitespace.

Comment: @undergroundmonorail ok thanks for the True/1 tip. I'm not used to that since Java Dosent do that. I didn't know that Python had semicolons either. I'll look into that

Answer (score 3):

### Pure bash, <s>116 113</s> 96 bytes

Using bash version >= 5.0, there is a new `EPOCHREALTIME` variable:

```
for((;;)){
IFS=. read s m<<<$EPOCHREALTIME
printf '%(%c)T\n'
sleep .$[(3000000-10#$m)%1000000]
}
```

This will output something like:

```
mar 03 jan 2023 10:28:27
mar 03 jan 2023 10:28:28
mar 03 jan 2023 10:28:29
...
```

**Note:** In order to save 3 byte, I've done something to not do: mixing  `time()` (`printf '%()T'`) and `gettimeofday()` (`$EPOCHREALTIME`). [See: *WARNING! About mixing $EPOCHSECONDS and $EPOCHREALTIME*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58557346/1765658) (better line 3 would be: `printf '%(%c)T.%s\n' $s`)!!

### With a little more precision:

```
for((;;)){
IFS=. read s m<<<$EPOCHREALTIME
printf '%(%c)T.%s\n' $s $m
read -rn1 -t .$[(3000000-10#$m)%1000000] _
}
```

Will output something like:

```
mar 03 jan 2023 10:52:44.183297
mar 03 jan 2023 10:52:45.000324
mar 03 jan 2023 10:52:46.000424
mar 03 jan 2023 10:52:47.000300
mar 03 jan 2023 10:52:48.000341
...
```

Comment: Woah, thems be some complicated bash

Comment: Yes, but without any external binary! (even no `sleep`)

Answer (score 3):

### K, <strike>25</strike> 24 Bytes

Removed semicolon from the end of the func!

```
      .z.ts:{-1@$18h$x}
      \t 1000
  13:11:44
  13:11:45
  13:11:46
  13:11:47
  13:11:48
  ...


.z.ts is called every 1000 milliseconds. 
x is the time. 
18$x casts the time to the appropriate format. 
$ - strings the result. 
-1@(stringed result) - prints the string to the console.
```

*Edit Below is less but I wasn't sure whether the time format was allowed;

```
    .z.ts:{-1($x)}
    \t 1000
2016.08.01D00:35:37.392683000
```

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, <s>19</s> 16 bytes

It takes the relevant part of the datetime list and joins by colons. Then it passes till the second changes, with the entire thang wrapped in an infinite loop.

```
#j\:KP.d2WqeK.d8
```

While it obviously doesn't work online, you can check its main idea [here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=j%5C%3AKP.d2WqeK.d8%29j%5C%3AP.d2&debug=0).

Comment: @VoteToClose oh, I actually wrote that a couple mins before you posted. Figured it was okay since it was a catalog.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman That's not necessary, as proven by the Stuck answer and the TI-BASIC answer. It is still human-readable and it is the time.

Comment: Also, you don't need to cut it for just the time string. ;P

Answer (score 2):

### Mathematica, <s>41</s> 36 bytes

```
While[1>0,Echo@DateString[];Pause@1]
```

Works as a script.

Answer (score 2):

## Matlab, <s>50</s> 42 bytes

```
while 1;pause(1);disp(datestr(now,13));end
```

Comment: I believe you can use the predefined numeric date format `13` instead of `'HH:MM:SS'` and save 8 bytes.

Comment: Somehow I'm noticed this a bit late, but thank you very much!

Comment: Perfect score! :D

Answer (score 2):

## C/C++, 219 Bytes

Here is a first pass attempt. It is written in C++ but uses only C functionalities, so it could be used as C code with only changes to the include statements (I think).

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctime>
time_t r;struct tm*x;int main(){char c[9],b[9];time(&r);x=localtime(&r);strftime(c,9,"%T",x);puts(c);for(;;){time(&r);x=localtime(&r);strftime(b,9,"%T",x);if(b[7]!=c[7]){break;} }main();}
```

I think everything is pretty straightforward. It takes the time at the beginning of the main function, then it continues getting time until one second has passed. It then calls itself.

Ungolfed:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctime>
time_t r;struct tm*x;
int main(){
    char c[9];char b[9];
    time(&r);
    x=localtime(&r);
    strftime(c,9,"%T",x);
    puts(c);
    for(;;){
        time(&r);
        x=localtime(&r);
        strftime(b,9,"%T",x);
        if(b[7]!=c[7]){break;} // break when the 'second' changes
    }
    main();
}
```

Comment: Erm... I'm not the best with C, but won't this cause a StackOverflow (if I remember right, this might be java seeping in)?

Comment: It doesn't on my computer (using g++) although int main(){main();} does cause a seg fault.

Comment: @VoteToClose I believe that tail recursion gets optimized away.

Comment: I get a segfault at about 40000 lines in (removed the waiting system). Don't think it _particularly_ matters at that far in, though.

Comment: Okay so it does crash eventually. That makes sense. If that's an issue, it isn't too hard to change it to a loop for a few extra bytes

Comment: ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ I don't really see a problem with 11.1111... hours of runtime max.

Comment: With the `-O2` switch, gcc/g++ will perform tail call optimization. I'm not sure that's strictly necessary for this answer (since VTC already said it's fine as-is), but it's helpful to know. :)

Comment: You can `#include<cstdio>` instead of `stdio.h`.

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, <s>25</s> 24 bytes

*Thanks @manatwork for golfing off a byte :P*

```
loop{puts`date;sleep 1`}
```

Not bad.

Comment: `print`? Either `puts` or `$><<` are shorter with identical result.

Comment: Derp. Thanks for that. (You can tell I don't use Ruby much :P)

Answer (score 2):

## Vimscript, 44 bytes

```
while 1
echo strftime("%T")
sleep 1
endwhile
```

Run like so:

```
vim -c ":so FILE"
```

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 33 bytes

```php
<?for(;;)sleep(print date("r
"));
```

Output is similar to `Sat, 28 Nov 2015 11:25:16 +0700`, i.e. RFC 2822.

Comment: Not sure wether this is allowed. This doesn't output every second for me. This only creates a time value once per second, but doesnt actually show me.

Comment: Are you invoking from the command line, e.g. `php time.php`?

Answer (score 2):

## Go, <s>64</s> <s>69</s> 79 bytes

Go isn't very golfy.

```
package main;import(."fmt";."time");func main(){for{Println(Now());Sleep(1e9)}}
```

You *could* try it [here](http://play.golang.org) or on [another online interpreter](http://ideone.com) however, `for{}` is an infinite loop and those are disallowed for obvious reasons. <s>I haven't actually tested this<sup>there are no go interpreters for my android ):</sup> but it should work in theory.</s>

Running it locally might cause your CPU fan to speed up, but it won't hog memory. If it crashes with some sort of OOM-error or `panic: runtime out of bound`, just change it to `for x:=0;x<9999;x++{ ... }`.

Comment: This sleeps for [one nanosecond](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Duration), which results in multiple outputs per second. You'll need `Sleep(Second)` to fix this.

Comment: `Sleep(1e9)` would work, no? I don't remember very much about Go, but I remember something like that.

Comment: @MichaelHampton fixed, thanks

Comment: @VoteToClose Yes, `1e9` works fine on my cgo 1.5.1...

Comment: I'm sitting at a PC so I can test it; it works.

Comment: Woo, helped golf a language I've never used! \o/

Comment: @VoteToClose The funny part is that `gofmt` puts all the whitespace back in, so Go never wins these sorts of competitions. Then again, it's a _very_ readable language, and lots of fun to work with.

Comment: No, Go never wins [tag:code-golf] because *every* program starts with `package main\nfunc main () {\n`, not because it's beautiful and readable when *formatted*. I write my Go using lint-on-save and then golf it manually.

Comment: Well yes, that too. I'm using syntastic and vim-go, which has about the same result...

Comment: [At least it's not Java.](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/5829/44713)

Answer (score 2):

## CJam, 21 bytes

```
L{et6<':*_@={_oNo}|}h
```

[Try it online!](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=THtldDY8JzoqX0A9e19vTm99fH1o&input=) Note that the online interpreter will kill the program after one minute.

Same idea, but with pretty output:

```
L{et6<3>"%02d:"fe%sW<_@={_oNo}|}h
```

[Try it online!](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=THtldDY8Mz4iJTAyZDoiZmUlc1c8X0A9e19vTm99fH1o&input=)

Answer (score 2):

## SpecBAS - 45 bytes

Prints in the upper left corner for a continuously updating 24 hour clock. Pressing Esc stops it running.

```
1 TEXT AT 0,0;TIME$(TIME,"hh:mm:ss"): GO TO 1
```

Comment: I don't know if this answer would be shorter, but you don't have to necessarily just have the time string. If you output a time string with extraneous data (but still containing the time string), that is fine, so you _might_ have a shorter answer in store.

Comment: TIME on it's own returns a decimal number (days since 30/12/1899!) which then needed formatting to hours/min/secs format. There isn't a function/statement that just returns already formatted date/time string unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

### Ceylon, <s>126</s> 112 bytes

`import ceylon.time{now}void p(){for(e in{now().time().string[0:8]}.cycled.paired){if(e[0]!=e[1]){print(e[1]);}}}`

This uses the [ceylon.time library](https://modules.ceylon-lang.org/repo/1/ceylon/time/1.2.0/module-doc/api/index.html) for getting the current time (in the default timezone) and formatting it (the `.string` function for time outputs something like `22:33:45.234`, so I just take the first 8 characters of it).

Unfortunately, [there seems to be no `sleep` function in Ceylon (because it is not easy to implement in JavaScript)](https://github.com/ceylon/ceylon/issues/5474), therefore I'm doing a busy loop here, comparing each formatted string to the previous one and printing only when there is a change.

Here is a formatted version of the second version, which uses a for-loop over an infinite iterable:

```
// print the current time (each second).
//
// Question:  http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/65020/2338
// My answer: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/65130/2338

import ceylon.time {
    now
}

void p() {
    for(e in { now().time().string[0:8] }.cycled.paired) {
        if(e[0]!=e[1]) {
            print(e[1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Using a `<` instead of `!=` would save a character, but then the program would stop working as soon as the clock hits midnight.

This was the original, more functional, version resulting in 112 characters:

```
import ceylon.time {
    now
}

void p() {
    { now().time().string[0:8] }
        .cycled
        .paired
        .map((e) => e[0] != e[1] then e[1])
        .coalesced
        .each(print);
}
```

Comment: Is `n=now` saving you bytes if you only use it once? I don't know Ceylon, but it seems redundant.

Comment: @sysreq actually, no ... for this three-letter identifier it doesn't safe anything (though it also doesn't cost bytes). I'll change this.

Answer (score 2):

### Processing, 68 bytes

```
void draw(){frameRate(1);println(hour()+":"+minute()+":"+second());}
```

Easy one I have to admit. In processing there is the `draw()` method which is called at a specific frequency that can be modified during the execution.

Comment: Can you show an example output? :D

Comment: A new line every seconds (represented by the spaces) ```22:42:32
22:42:33
22:42:34
22:42:35
22:42:36
22:42:37```

Comment: Oh, so it's not graphical output?

Comment: No, that's printed in the console. I'm just "exploiting" the draw method as a loop.

Comment: Ohh, I see. Well done, +1 (in about an hour - can't vote right now. :c)

Answer (score 2):

## [Hassium](http://HassiumLang.com), 43 Bytes

```
func main(){print(time())sleep(1000)main()}
```

See expanded [here](http://hassiumlang.com/Paste/get-paste.has?hash=894d2c7290af6f7bcbc5702c6409addf)

Answer (score 2):

### sh (+ top), 7 bytes

Script (Debian8):

```
top -d1
```

Script (NetBSD7):

```
top -s1
```

(both without trailing newline)

Output (1st line only, Debian8):

```
top - 16:25:15 up 3 days,  8:56,  4 users,  load average: 0,97, 1,10, 1,03
```

Output (1st line only, NetBSD7, different time zone):

```
load averages:  1.46,  1.28,  1.22; (SPACES) up 44+08:52:28 (SPACES) 15:22:06
```

The amount of spaces depends on the terminal width.

Answer (score 2):

### C, <s>74</s> 73 bytes

```
#include<time.h>
main(){for(time_t t;!sleep(1);time(&t))puts(ctime(&t));}
```

The code can work even without `#include <stdio.h>` and `#include <unistd.h>`, see [live code example on `ideone.com`](http://ideone.com/1jtE55) -- note: the sleep is zero there, to generate some output before the time limit has been exceeded.

The first output line should be ignored ([*"Extra output doesn't really matter, as long as the program at some point continuously outputs time."*](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65020/output-the-current-time#comment157287_65020)).

Comment: 66 bytes: `#include<time.h> t;main(){for(;time(&t);sleep(1))puts(ctime(&t));}`

Answer (score 2):

### Python 3, 48 bytes

```
from time import*
while[sleep(1)]:print(ctime())
```

It is a [@Mego's Python 2 solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/65032/1004) tweaked to work on Python 3.
Here's [Jupyter notebook to see the results and try it](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/zed/b987a6b66b8316b88830).

Answer (score 2):

## PureBasic, <s>64</s> 59 bytes

Not much to say, infinite loop, output time to the debug window with a 1000 millisecond delay

```
a:
Debug FormatDate("%hh:%ii:%ss",Date())
Delay(1e3)
Goto a
```

Comment: ForEver? Seems legit.

Comment: the comment on ForEver made me think about infinite loops and all it boils down to is a Goto loop and it saved me 5 bytes :D

Comment: Goto? Even better. ;D Can you put the `a:` directly before `Debug...` to remove the newline? Or is that a different version of BASIC?

Comment: nope, labels for goto's have to be the only statement on the line for it to work. The colon is generally used for stringing multiple commands on one line, so you could have "Debug FormatDate("%hh:%ii:%ss",Date()):Delay(1e3):Goto a"

Answer (score 2):

## Prolog (SWI), 72 bytes

Formating to user_output stops working when using sleep, so I had to save the time to a variable and print it explicitly.

**Code:**

```
p:-repeat,get_time(T),format_time(atom(X),'%T',T),write(X),sleep(1),1=0.
```

**Explained:**

```
p:-repeat,                      % loop until success
   get_time(T),                 % Get current timestamp
   format_time(atom(X),'%T',T), % Format timestamp as HH:mm:ss
   write(X),                    % Print time
   sleep(1),                    % Sleep 1 second
   1=0.                         % Fail and go back to repeat
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Vitsy](https://github.com/VTCAKAVSMoACE/Vitsy) + bash, <s>13</s> 11 bytes

<sub>This language feature was made after this question, but not for this question.</sub>

```
<w1Z,'date'
<           Loop leftwards in the code.
            Rest of code is written in reverse for "readability". 
 'etad'     Push 'date' to the stack.
       ,    Do the shell script for what's in the stack.
        Z   Output the result.
         1w Wait a second.
```

Or, using eval...

```
<w1Zn"Date()"
<             Go leftwards through this code in order to loop infinitely. 

              Rest of code is written in reverse for "readability". 

 ")(etaD"     Push "Date()" to the stack.
         n    Eval through JS.
          Z   Output everything.
           1w Delay for one second.
```

[Try it online!](http://vitsy.tryitonline.net/#code=PHcxWm4iRGF0ZSgpIg&input=)

Comment: `sleep 1` based answer break rule 5: *you must guarantee one, and only one, output of time per second*... anymore!!

Comment: @F.Hauri Please read rule 6 - also, stop spamming me.

Answer (score 2):

### QBasic, 16 bytes

Shamelessly stole (and imporoved upon) Mauris' design:

```
CLS:?TIME$:RUN
```

---

Previous version: 24 bytes

EDIT: Only just saw that I don't have to SLEEP 1 if I continuously clear the screen and print the time. That's 4 bytes shorter:

```
DO:CLS:PRINT TIME$:LOOP
```

---

Previous entry (28 bytes)

```
DO:PRINT TIME$:SLEEP 1:LOOP
```

Nothing fancy, not too shabby.

Answer (score 2):

## [Mouse-2002](https://github.com/catb0t/newmouse/blob/master/mouse.c), 84 bytes

Mouse is cool, but it's not the golfiest stack based language on the planet (well, not until I update it in a reimplementation -- then it will be better.)

```
0&FIX 2&WIDTH "!"(&HOUR &!DEC ":"&MIN &!DEC ":"&SEC &!DEC 8!'8!'8!'8!'8!'8!'8!'8!')$
```

The `8!'` prints the character with ASCII code 8, or `backspace`. You probably need an ANSI terminal to run this; it updates in place by backspacing over itself and writing the new time once per second.

sample use:

```
$ mouse clock2.mou

19:47:34
```

Based on [this](http://mouse.davidgsimpson.com/mouse2002/clock2_mou.txt), but golfed.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, 85 bytes

```
import time;while 1:print __import__('datetime').datetime.now().time();time.sleep(1)
```

`import time;time.sleep()` has 2 fewer bytes than `__import__('time').sleep()`, while `import datetime;datetime.datetime.now()` has 2 more bytes than `__import__('datetime').datetime.now()`.

Answer (score 2):

## Emacs Lisp, 83 bytes

```
(run-with-timer 1 1(lambda()(message(format-time-string"%H:%M:%S"(current-time)))))
```

Answer (score 2):

### bash, 35 bytes

Just for kicks

```
yes|mapfile -tc1 -C'date;sleep 1 #'
```

Also 35,

```
x='x[`date>&2;sleep 1`${!x}]'<${!x}
```

I think it's unlikely there's anything shorter than `exec $0`.

Comment: Are you sure the first solution is not als0 35 characters long? I have to put a space in front of the `#` otherwise `sleep` cries for invalid syntax.

Comment: @manatwork Yes. Looks like I tested a version that did `;:` before I changed it to `#` and made a typo. The `interactive_comments` shopt sometimes screws with me too. Good catch.

Answer (score 2):

### Groovy, <s>40</s> 37 bytes

Not very golfable :(, thanks to FlagAsSpam for for(;;) :)

```
for(;;){print(new Date());sleep 1000}
```

Comment: `for(;;){...`? And what about 1e3 for 1000? You can use `print` instead of `println`.

Comment: Thanks, I was pretty sure it needs to be a new line every time.

Answer (score 2):

### [Lua](http://www.lua.org), 56 bytes

Lua is pretty hard to golf...

```
v=1
while 1 do v=os.date'%c' l=v~=l and print(v)or v end
```

There are few online interpreters that allow infinite loops; one of the few I've found is [this one](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_lua_online.php). This repeatedly converts the current system time to a date-time string and outputs that string when it's different from the last.

Ungolfed:

```
current = 1
while 1 do 
    current = os.date('%c') 
    last = current ~= last and print(current) or current
end
```

Comment: +1 for golfing in lua :). You can golf it down to 51 bytes by using a label+goto to do an infinite loop, and suppress some spaces : `v=1::a::v=os.date'%c'l=v~=l and print(v)or v goto a`

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), 11 bytes

```
`Z'0XOD1Y.T
```

[**Try it here**](https://matl.suever.net/?code=%60Z%270XOD1Y.T&inputs=&version=18.6.0).

#### Explanation

```
`         % do...while loop
  Z'      %   get current date and time  
  0XO     %   string representation of date and time, with format 'dd-mmm-yyyy HH:MM:SS'
  D       %   convert to string and display           
  1Y.     %   pause for 1 second
  T       %   push "true" value as loop condition to create infinite loop
          % implicitly end loop
```

Comment: Why non competing?

Comment: @SocraticPhoenix Becuase the language is newer than the challenge. I've clarified that in the answer

Comment: unless I'm mistaken, this is a catalog challenge, meaning you can post languages that are newer...

Comment: Yep, "Since this is a catalog, languages created after this challenge are allowed to compete"

Comment: @SocraticPhoenix Oh, thanks! I hadn't noticed. I'll remove the note then

Answer (score 2):

## Perl 6, <s>34</s> 30 bytes

Perl 6 is looooong, but I like it.
Yes, all the whitespace is needed.

```
sleep 1 while say DateTime.now
```

Hooray for postfix syntax!

Answer (score 2):

### F#, <s>101</s> 98 bytes

```
open System;while 1=1 do(DateTime.Now.ToString"HH:MM:ss"|>printfn"%s";Threading.Thread.Sleep 1000)
```

Pretty straightforward: print the current time in the correct format, wait a second, then repeat. Forever.

Credit to @VoteToClose and @RikerW for the help.

Comment: Few questions: is `for(;;)` valid syntax? Can you use `DateTime.Now.ToString"HH:MM:ss"`? Do you need the whitespace in `; Threading.Thread.Sleep`

Comment: Few answers! From [what I've seen](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233236.aspx), `for(;;)` sadly isn't valid F#. The other two suggestions are dead on, however - I can't believe I've overlooked those. Thanks! =)

Comment: `while (truthy value)`?

Comment: @RikerW Right, that's another good one. I usually write infinite loops as recursive functions, so I hadn't thought about it. Thanks! =)

Comment: Not just plain `1`?

Comment: @RikerW Because of F#'s strong typing, that doesn't work. The only truthy value is `true`, of type `bool`. Anything else won't type-check - if I put in `while 1 do`, I get this error: `stdin(1,7): error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type bool but here has type int`.

Comment: Okay, just checking. So 1=1 is the shortest possible.

Comment: Does `Threading.Thread.Sleep 1e3` work?

Comment: @VoteToClose I didn't know if `1e3` was valid F#, so I tried it just now. Turns out that it works! Well, kinda - it evaluates to `1000.0`, but `Sleep` doesn't have an overload that takes a `float`. Still, I learned something new! =)

Answer (score 2):

## Rebol, 25 bytes

```
forever[print now wait 1]
```

This prints day & time (24 hour HH:MM:SS).  For an extra 5 bytes you can make it print just the time: `forever[print now/time wait 1]`

Comment: Lol, is it said that I read this like house music? Print, now wait 1. Print, now wait 1.

Answer (score 2):

## Batch (Windows), 21 bytes

### t.bat

```
echo %time%
timeout 1
t
```

Shows the time, delays for 1 second, then recursively calls itself. This is run as `t.bat` in the same directory.

Comment: I count 43, but you also need to count the name. If you rename the file to A, then you can bring the score down to 38.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Answer (score 2):

## Pascal, 144 B

This `program` requires a processor complying to the ISO standard 10206 “Extended Pascal”, e. g. the [GNU Pascal Compiler](https://www.GNU-Pascal.de/) (GPC).
It’s doing a [busy wait](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting) until the time changes.
*The second* line of the entire output will probably be printed in significantly less than a 1 second interval.

```pascal
program t(output);var t:timeStamp;s:string(8);begin s:='';repeat getTimeStamp(t);if s<>time(t)then begin s:=time(t);writeLn(s)end until 6=9 end.
```

The code does not check `timeStamp.timeValid`, so on a system *without a clock* this program will print just a single line representing midnight, `getTimeStamp`’s default value if `timeStamp.timeValid` is set to `false`.

The return value of `time` is **implementation-defined**.
It may be in an AM/PM format, military time, or something else.
Thus it’s not guaranteed that the challenge’s specifications are met.
At any rate, *the GPC’s* implementation returns something in the style of `22:00:42`.
This fits into a `string(8)`.
A different Pascal implementation may require more characters in order to detect a change in time.

Also, if you [don’t mind](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods) a *preceding* empty line, you can use this **134 B** `program`:

```pascal
program t(output);var x:timeStamp;s:string(8);begin s:='';repeat getTimeStamp(x);if s<>time(x)then writeLn(s);s:=time(x)until 6=9 end.
```

Answer (score 1):

### TI-BASIC, 29 bytes

```
While 1
Output(1,1,getTimeStr(24)+":
Output(1,7,sum(getTime,3
End
```

TI-BASIC has a built-in `getTimeStr`, but it doesn't display seconds! How to fix this? Just display the seconds over the empty space after the minutes. (It would be much easier if there were a way to convert numbers to strings.)

Outputs in 24-hour mode.

Comment: I count 65 bytes there... how do you get 29?

Comment: @Fozzedout TI-BASIC uses a tokenized encoding of one or two bytes per token.

Answer (score 1):

## C#, <s>129</s> 125 bytes

```c#
using System;using System.Threading;class P{static void Main(){for(;;){Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);Thread.Sleep(1000);}}}
```

Ungolfed:

```c#
using System;
using System.Threading;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        for (;;)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know C# but can't you do `for(;;)` instead of `while(true)`?

Comment: Updated, thanks @muddyfish

Comment: Can you do 1e3 over 1000? (I don't know C# either.)

Comment: Thread.Sleep accepts either int or TimeSpan.  You can do Thread.Sleep((int)1e3) but that's longer unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 24 bytes

```
for(;;)echo date("\rr");
```

`\r` clears the current line before printing the date/time using the `r` flag. Therefor it doesn't have to wait or delay the output for a second. Also the cursor is always positioned behind the output, which would be different for `r\r` where it would overlay the first character of the output.

Comment: _"You must output the current time continuously (until cancelled by an interrupt), once every second"_ ... not every millisecond.

Comment: @yeti See the OP's current last comment on the question: "*If it's only one visible output per second, then that should be fine.*".

Comment: Changing the rules in comments is not a good idea... he better should update the original text instead... :-(

Comment: Shouldn't PHP code always include the short open tag or add bytes for using the -r switch? Otherwise, this script will just print the source code.

Comment: @YetiCGN It's accepted throughout this site to not include the PHP opening tag in the byte count. Here's a [discussion](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/7098/41859) about it that also links to a few related posts.

Comment: Good to know, I will be 2 bytes better on most challenges from now on!

Answer (score 1):

## AppleScript, <s>112</s> <s>93</s> 45 bytes

```
repeat
delay 1
log(do shell script"date")
end
```

This repeats in a loop, does the bash script `date`, gets its returned string, and outputs it to the `Messages` pane. Why I didn't do this at first, I'll never know.

#### Using Node:

Let's have a <s>odd</s> useless combination, shall we?

This was inspired by my [Vitsy answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/66114/44713), which also uses JS to get the date.

```
tell app"System Events"
tell app"Terminal"to activate
keystroke"node
"
repeat
delay 1
keystroke"Date()
"
end
end
```

What I do here is I tell the System Events application to get terminal as the front window, then enter `node` with the terminal by telling System Events to simulate keystrokes of `n`, `o`, `d`, `e`, followed by a newline. It then enters a loop in which it delays for a second, tells node to do `Date()` by the same method, then going back to the top of the loop.

This answer is mostly to demonstrate the odd things that Applescript allows you to do.

Comment: `sleep 1` based answer break rule 5: *you must guarantee one, and only one, output of time per second*!!

Comment: @F.Hauri I've seen you posting this on most things in this question, but read rule 6 carefully as to why this is not always the case. ;)

Answer (score 1):

## Unix Shell + procps, 12 bytes

`procps` is a package providing CLI utils for browsing `procfs`, a virtual filesystem generated by the kernel to provide information about processes.

The `watch` command reruns a command every on an interval, that defaults to `2`. Set it to `1`, and run `.`, and voilá, `watch` suppresses stderr.

```
watch -n1 .
```

The time is in the upper right.

---

incidentally, `watch` is very handy for spying on the progress of a lengthy `dd` or `cp`.

Comment: I think you meant `:` (a colon). A single `.` is shorthand for `source`. `source` without any arguments should _complain_ about missing arguments. Also, I think `‑‑precise`/`‑p` would be adequate here. “Incidentally” `dd` has `status=progress` so a periodic `pkill ‑USR1 '^dd$'` isn’t necessary. I’m not sure how you combine `watch` and `cp`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
7ŒTṄœS1ß
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=N8WSVOG5hMWTUzHDnw&input=)

#### How it works

```
7ŒTṄœS1ß  Main link. No arguments.

7         Yield 7 (or 111 in binary).
 ŒT       Time; return hours, minutes and seconds (lower three bits).
   Ṅ      Print, followed by a linefeed.
      1   Yield 1.
    œS    Sleep for 1 second, return the time.
       ß  Call the main link recursively.
```

Answer (score 1):

## Factor, 43 bytes

```
[ [ t ] [ now "%c" strftime print ] while ]
```

An anoymous function. Use it like `~quotation~ call`.

Comment: I thought it was supposed to output the time once per second. This outputs as often as possible.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pylongolf](https://github.com/lvivtotoro/pylongolf), 11 bytes

```
>}~.1000w.<
```

`}~` pushes the current time into the stack and then prints it.
`.` the dots reset the stack.
`1000w` pushes 1000 into the stack and then waits that time.

Comment: This not seems to output the time continuously, once per second.

Comment: Fixed the problem!

Answer (score 1):

## Python, 53 bytes

This one prints the date and year as well as the time, so I don't know if it's allowed.

```
import time
while 1:print(time.ctime());time.sleep(1)
```

EDIT: J.F.Sebastian made a shorter one.

Answer (score 1):

## [Tellurium](http://m654z.github.io/Tellurium), 8 bytes

```
[i|t^¨]
```

The code that is after the `|` and before the `]` is run forever (`i`).

It changes the value of the current cell to the current time (`t`), outputs the current cell's value using `^`, and waits for 1 second (`¨`) before continuing.

Comment: "Since this is a catalog, languages created after this challenge are allowed to compete." Hey, what are you waiting for?

Comment: @zyabin101 Fixed that! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

## Scratch, 15 bytes

[image: Scratch Script]
([scoring used](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/673/golfing-in-scratch))
This script is essentially what it says.  It joins the hour value, then a colon, then the minute value, then a colon, then the second value.  The downside is that Scratch reads 01 as 1, so it might not be valid without making the script longer.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to PPCG! According to Meta, that is 15 bytes, one for each block, and one for each character of text.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I linked the meta post in question for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, <s>27</s> 21 bytes

With 2 bytes saved thanks to Xavier.

```
Dynamic@{Now,Clock[]}
```

Comment: 25 bytes with `Dynamic@{Now,Clock@{1,2}}`, and 21 with: `Dynamic@{Now,Clock[]}`.

Answer (score 1):

### [Lua](http://www.lua.org), 51 Bytes

Since the previous owner of [this answer in 56 Bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/68635/41019) doesn't update anymore when suggested improvments, here's a 51 Bytes solution heavily based on his:

```lua
v=1::a::v=os.date'%c'l=v~=l and print(v)or v goto a
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Nim](http://nim-lang.org/), <s>55</s> 54 bytes

```
import os,times
while on:echo getClockStr();sleep 1000
```

`on` is an alias for `true`. Prints the result of the `times` module's `getClockStr` proc, which formats the time nicely in 24-hour format, then uses the `os` module's `sleep` proc to sleep a second.

Answer (score 1):

## C#, 102 bytes

```
using System;class P{static void Main(){for(var s="";;)if(s!=(s=DateTime.Now+"\n"))Console.Write(s);}}
```

An infinite loop that prints whenever the time changes. Default precision for C# date printing is to the second, so that works out nicely.

Answer (score 1):

## Fourier, <s>46</s> 20 bytes

This is a fairly simple program which loops infinitely, using the newly added [**date functions**](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fourier#date), [**delay function**](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fourier#delay) and [**clear screen function**](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fourier#cls).

This does not show a leading zero on the minutes or the seconds value when either are less than ten.

```
(@2do58a1do58a0do1;)
```

[**Try it online!**](https://beta-decay.github.io/editor/?code=KEAyZG81OGExZG81OGEwZG8xOyk)

<sub>***Note:* this program will not work on http://fourier.tryitonline.net due to differences in the way interpreters work.**</sub>

Answer (score 1):

## tcl, 67

```
while 1 {puts [clock format [clock seconds] -format %T];after 1000}
```

can be tested on: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_tcl_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMUkViT2lXWDlLYlE

Answer (score 1):

### Clojure, 140 bytes

```clj
(loop[l 0](let[c(System/nanoTime)](recur(if(>=(- c l)1e3)(do(println(.format(java.text.SimpleDateFormat."h:m:s a")(java.util.Date.)))c)l))))
```

Full program. Loops continually; keeping track of the last time it printed. If 1000ms have passed, it prints, then resets the time.

Java interop really bloats this up, but not much can be done about that.

Ungolfed:

```clj
(defn current-time []
  (loop [last-ns 0]
    (let [current-time (System/nanoTime)]
      (recur
        (if (>= (- current-time last-ns) 1e3)
          (do
            (println (.format (java.text.SimpleDateFormat. "h:m:s a") (java.util.Date.)))
            current-time)
          last-ns)))))
```

### Using `sleep` (which seems to be of questionable validity), 100 bytes

```clj
(while[](Thread/sleep 1e3)(println(.format(java.text.SimpleDateFormat."h:m:s a")(java.util.Date.))))
```

Ungolfed:

```clj
(defn current-time []
  (while []
    (Thread/sleep 1e3)
    (println (.format (java.text.SimpleDateFormat. "h:m:s a") (java.util.Date.)))))
```

Answer (score 1):

## [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 6 bytes (nc)

```
{_C?_d
```

QBIC is newer than this challenge. In fact, this challenge is the reason QBIC has a `_C` command (for `CLS` - Clear the screen) and the `_d/_D` commands (for `TIME$` and `DATE$` resp).

### Explanation

```
{        Start infinite loop
 _C      Clear screen
   ?     PRINT
    _d   TIME$ (which holds the system's time in QBasic)
```

Answer (score 1):

## MOO, 46 bytes

```
while(!suspend(!player:tell(ctime())))endwhile
```

Sleeps for one second between outputs, regardless of execution time (and it's impossible to know sub-second timings anyway

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 29 bytes

```factor
[ now hh:mm:ss nl ] 1e9 every
```

Normally you'd give `every` a duration for more readability: `[ ... ] 1 seconds every` but if you just give it a number, it'll interpret it as nanoseconds.

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, <s>36</s> 34 bytes

```
a:echo'
'.date(r);sleep(1);goto a;
```

The line break can be \n but it's nicer to convert the script to the old Macintosh line format and make it \r, then the time is neatly updated on the same line.

Updates:

1. Removed short open tag as per [this meta answer](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2428/58556)

Comment: `for(;;sleep(1))...` saves three bytes. `echo date("\nr");` is not shorter, but looks cleaner imo.

Answer (score 0):

## 05AB1E, 13 bytes

```
[žažbžc)':ý,w
```

Should work, but I don't have Python 3, so I can't test.

Answer (score 0):

## [Elixir](http://elixir-lang.org), 95 bytes

```
def f, do: 1000|>Stream.interval|>Enum.each(&(&1&&DateTime.utc_now|>DateTime.to_time|>IO.puts))
```

Answer (score 0):

## [*><>](//esolangs.org/wiki/Starfish), 16 bytes

```
'::'hnomnosnaoaS
```

[000webhostapp interpreter.](//starfish.000webhostapp.com?script=OQLhwCwOwewW1gZygQxigykA)

Note: it sometimes skips a second (e.g. 12:34:6 → 12:34:8), because you can't wait *exactly a second* with total accuracy. Unfortunately there isn't any way to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

## VBA, 50 Bytes

Anonymous VBE immediate window function that takes no input and outputs to the VBE immdiate window

```vba
Do:DoEvents:?Now:Application.Wait 1/864E2+Now:Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Phooey](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Phooey), 39 bytes

```
[1@_1~t/1000@/60@/60%24[_1%60$i":"&]#1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8jIz0@t/P8/2tAh3rCuRN/QwMDAQd8MjFWNTKLjDVXNDFQylayU1GKVDWP//wcA)

It's not pretty. It prints the time followed by another colon, with no newline in between.

In order to see the output you probably need to use `stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0` to set it to unbuffered, as I don't print newlines. The output is always in UTC time.

Explanation:

```c
[1            // While tape value is not 1 (it will either be 0 the first time or -1 the second)
  @_1         // Push sentinel of negative 1
  ~t          // tape = millis since epoch
  /1000       // Divide tape by 1000 to get seconds
  @           // Push tape value to save the seconds
  /60         // Divide by 60 to get minutes
  @           // Push tape to save minutes
  /60         // Divide by 60 to get hours
  %24         // Modulo by 24 to hour of the day
              // Stack: -1, seconds, minutes
              // Tape: hours
  [_1         // While tape is not -1 sentinel
     %60      //   modulo tape by 60 (redundant for hours)
     $i       //   print as number
     ":"      //   print separator
     &        //   Pop to tape
  ]           // Loop if tape == tape (nop condition)
  #1          // sleep 1 second
]             // End loop
```

Note: 2:58 PM EST = 18:58 UTC

Excuse the low quality, the attachment feature has a stupid requirement of 2 MB which is not easy for GIFs to reach...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## x86-16 DOS .COM executable (FreeDOS 1.3), 40 bytes

```
00000000: b4 2c cd 21 38 f3 74 f8 88 f3 88 e8 e8 07 00 91  .,.!8.t.........
00000010: e8 03 00 88 d8 56 d4 0a 05 30 30 86 c4 cd 29 88  .....V...00...).
00000020: e0 cd 29 b0 3a cd 29 c3                          ..).:.).
```

Assembly source code:

```clojure
    ; NASM syntax
    [org 0x100]
start:
    ; Note: The first second may be a little off due to synchronizing to the time
.loop:
    ; Int 21:2C: get time
    ; Return:
    ;    CH = hour
    ;    CL = minute
    ;    DH = second
    ;    DL = 1/100 seconds
    mov   ah, 0x2C
    int   0x21
    ; If seconds is the same as before, try again.
    cmp   bl, dh
    jz    .loop
.loop.end:
    ; Save last seconds
    mov   bl, dh
    ; Print hours
    mov   al, ch
    call  print
    ; Print minutes
    ; mov al, cl
    xchg  ax, cx
    call  print
    ; print seconds
    mov al, bl
    ; Assume SI = 0x0100, push that as a return address
    ; and fall through to loop
    push  si

    ; Converts AL to 2 digit ASCII and prints, followed by :
print:
    ; AL = AL % 10
    ; AH = AL / 10
    aam   10
    ; Convert to ASCII
    add   ax, '00' ; 0x3030
    ; Byteswap to get tens in AL, save ones in AH
    xchg  al, ah
    ; Print tens with int 29h
    int   0x29
    ; Then ones
    mov   al, ah
    int   0x29
    ; Then colon
    mov   al, ':'
    int   0x29
    ; Return from function
    ret
```

Like my other answer it isn't pretty but it does the job. It prints a `:` between each time.

Output on FreeDOS 1.3 on QEMU
[image: Output on FreeDOS 1.3 on QEMU]

Answer (score 0):

### HP‑41C series, 4 Bytes

This requires an HP‑41CX or an HP‑41C/CV with a time module plugged in.

```
CLKT    2 Bytes  select time-only display for CLOCK (default)
CLOCK   2 Bytes  displays clock, refreshes every second
```

NB:
`CLOCK` is effectively `OFF` if the system flag 49 (“low battery”) is set.