# Calculate Swatch Internet Time

Tags: code-golf, date

Output the **current time of day** as [Swatch Internet Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swatch_Internet_Time).

Specifically, output a three-digit (zero-padded) number of "[.beats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swatch_Internet_Time#Beats)" (1000ths of a day) which represent the current time of day in the Swatch Internet Time time zone of UTC+01:00 ("Biel Meantime").

For example, if the current time in UTC is `23:47`, then it is `00:47` in UTC+1 ("Biel Meantime"), and the output would be `032`.

**Examples**:

```
UTC Current Time  ->  SIT Output
23:47             ->  032
23:00             ->  000
11:00             ->  500
14:37             ->  651
```

The program should produce this output then immediately exit.

Output is to standard output (or equivalent). **Must be a complete, runnable program, not a function.** The program takes no input; it outputs the *current* time.

Comment: Possible [dupe](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/65020/31625)? From reading the article it looks like doing a minor amount of arithmetic on the output to that challenge. Perhaps if you described the intricacies of Swatch Internet Time within the post, it would be clearer whether or not this is a duplicate. That said, welcome to PPCG, I hope your first question goes well, but note we have a [sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2140/31625) where challenges can be posted for review.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Hmm, yes, you're right, it's not that far from that challenge. It differs in that Swatch Internet Time has a fixed time zone, different formatting, and that I've only required the program output the time once.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Though note that unlike that challenge, you can't usually use `date()` or equivalent here, but PHP is an exception.

Comment: SE policy is that I should not need to visit external sites to understand and answer your question and the same goes for challenges. I don't know what SIT is, and when the thing hosting your link blows up, neither will anyone else.

Comment: Some more sample inputs and outputs would be nice. This challenge might have been better were it steeped in [the Sandbox](https://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1)

Comment: What sort of precision is required?  Minute, hour, second ... for example if it is second, I need a factor of 0.69444 while for minutes 0.694 is sufficient (assuming a floored int as output)

Comment: `032` does not seem to be the right SIT output for UTC `23:47`. Presuming that the number of seconds is `0`, the correct output should be `990`.

Comment: I am voting to close this as "unclear what you're asking" because (a) we don't know what the format of the output should be, (b) neither do we know what the precision should be (up to hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds, etc.), and (c) the SIT example output given for the example input `23:47` seems to be completely wrong, so people would be immensely confused unless they were to go to the SIT Wikipedia page linked, which, as @cat said, could, and probably will, blow up sometime in the future.

Comment: @R.Kap Swatch Internet Time does not use UTC, it uses UTC+1. 23:47 UTC is 00:47 UTC+1, no?

Comment: @Andrea Well, I assumed that you were using UTC+1 by just saying UTC without any reference to any other time zone. You should have been more clear about what time zone you were using in the example, because I, and nor will a lot of other people, know if the time in it is using UTC-1, UTC-2, UTC-3, etc. and therefore will get very confused.

Comment: @R.Kap I agree with your points a) and b), but it's obvious that if SIT is based on UTC+1 and it's currently 23:47 UTC(+0), it's 00:47 UTC+1, which agrees with Andrea's example. Hopefully we can get the question clarified, because I don't think it's a duplicate of the Current Time question.

Comment: @R.Kap “UTC” is the reference point from which other time zones are defined, it's no more ambiguous than GMT. Nonetheless, the updated post is clearer.

Comment: I've edited the post to provide more clarity. It now specifies the time zone (even if this is redundant), the formatting of the output (three digits, zero-padded), and that the program does not run continuously.

Comment: I've also now summarised what a “.beat” is.

Comment: Looks good, I've voted to reopen, but could we have more test cases?

Comment: @cat Okay, I've added three more examples. Turns out the first example I gave was a good choice, because it catches out code that does the time zone conversion incorrectly, and it demonstrates zero-padding.

Comment: @Andrea Awesome! I made the content a little more to the point and easier to read, and I made the test cases parsable by regex, which is important to me.

Comment: @Andrea Why did you disallow function answer?

Comment: @aloisdg because requiring output means the program has to do more, and that interests me

Answer (score 6):

## PHP, 12 bytes

```
<?=@date(B);
```

But it can only be so short because PHP has built-in Swatch Internet Time support. So this answer isn't much fun.

---

`<?=` exits HTML mode and evaluates an expression, then echoes it.

`@` silences an error.

`date()` outputs the current time, formatting it with a given format string.

`B` is an undefined constant. In PHP, if you reference a constant that doesn't exist, you get back a string containing its name, and it also produces a “notice”-level error. Here, the `@` suppresses that error. `B` is the `date()` format code for Swatch Internet Time.

`;` terminates the expression.

---

If we assume PHP is being run with the default error-reporting settings, where “notices” are silenced, we could skip the `@`, and it would only be 11 bytes.

Comment: I'm pretty sure supresssing notices is actually the default for PHP golfing on this site

Comment: @SuperJedi224 It's PHP's default configuration, too, but I have it set to show notices on my machine, so…

Answer (score 5):

## C, *56 bytes*

```
main(){printf("%03d",(int)((time(0)+3600)%86400/86.4));}
```

Explanation:

- **%03d** - tells printf to zero-pad up to 3 digits.
- **time(NULL)+3600** - gets amount of seconds (UTC) elapsed since epoch and adds an hour to it (UTC+1).
- **%86400** - divides epoch by the amount of seconds in a 24hr day and gets the remainder (representing seconds elapsed, so far, "today").
- **/86.4** - divide remaining seconds by 86.4 to get the ".beat" count since midnight (UTC+1).

#### Compile (MSVC):

C:> cl swatch.c

#### Compile (GCC):

$ gcc swatch.c

Comment: For future reference: you should post the golfed version of the code, and, at your option, an ungolfed version or test program below.

Comment: This contains a bug. It doesn't do a modulo after correcting the time-zone, it does it *before*, which means between 23:00–0:00 UTC (i.e. 0:00–1:00 UTC+1), it incorrectly produces a four-digit number. You could fix this by changing `time(NULL)%86400+3600` to `(time(NULL)+3600)%86400`.

Comment: Also, you could save space by omitting the two includes, and replacing the `NULL` with `0`.

Comment: Hmm, doesn't `%03.f` round up? That would give inaccurate results.

Comment: @Andrea Thank you.  _Edited_.

Answer (score 3):

## PHP, <del>48</del> 46 bytes

```
<?=sprintf("%03d",((time()+3600)%86400)/86.4);
```

I have another PHP answer above, but this one avoids using PHP's built-in Swatch Internet Time support, so it's more interesting, if longer.

This is largely self-explanatory if you're familiar with UNIX time and `sprintf`, <del>though note I'm using `|0` as a short way to truncate a float to an integer</del> (actually I realised this is unnecessary in PHP, oops!)

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8, 143 bytes

```
import java.time.*;interface A{static void main(String[]a){System.out.format("%03.0f",LocalTime.now(ZoneId.of("UT+1")).toSecondOfDay()/86.4);}}
```

this uses Java 8's java.time package to get current time, convert it to UTC+1, and then get the number of seconds. At the end it divides by the number of 1000s of seconds in a day, which turns out to be 86.4.

Funny how the function that actually calculates the time is only about a third of the overall program size.

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript, <s>53</s> <s>52</s> 48 bytes

```
alert((new Date/864e5%1+1/24+'0000').slice(2,5))
```

Explanation:

`new Date/864e5%1` is the fraction of a day in UTC. `+1/24` adds 1/24th of a day (1 hour), moving it to UTC+1.

`"0000"` is concatenated with this, turning it into a string. Then the 3rd through 5th characters are taken. The reason `"0000"` is concatenated instead of an empty string is for the cases in which there are fewer than 3 decimal places:

- `"0.XXX`(any number of digits here)`0000"` Swatch time is XXX
- `"0.XX0000"` Swatch time is XX0
- `"0.X0000"` Swatch time is X00
- `"00000"` Swatch time is 000

(the first character is 1 instead of 0 from 23:00 UTC to 24:00 UTC, but the first character is ignored.)

Answer (score 2):

## 05AB1E, <s>29</s> 21 bytes

```
ža>60©%®*žb+₄*1440÷Dg3s-Å0š˜J
```

After compressing integers thanks to @KevinCruijssen (-8 bytes) :

```
ža>60©%®*žb+₄*Ž5¦÷₄+¦
```

Explanation:

```
ža>60©%®*žb+₄*1440÷Dg3s-Å0š˜J
ža                               push current hours in UT 
  >                              increment
   60©                           push 60 and save in register c
      %                          hours mod 60
       ®*                        push from register c and Multiply
         žb+                     add current minutes    
            ₄*                   multiply by 1000
              1440÷              Integer division with 1440
                   D             Duplicate
                    g            Length
                     3s-         3-length
                        Å0       create list of a 0s
                          š      Prepand
                           ˜J    Flat and joon
```

I didn't find a better idea for prepanding Zeros, so if anyone got a better idea I'll be glad to know :)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATEAzv9vc2FiaWX//8W@YT42MMKpJcKuKsW@YivigoQqMTQ0MMO3RGczcy3DhTDFocucSv//)

[Try the 21 bytes online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6L5EOzODQytVD63TOrovSftRU4vW0b2mh5Yd3g5kah9a9v8/AA)

Comment: The output of this is not three padded digits, no?

Comment: Also, is 694 accurate enough? (I don't know.)

Comment: You're right on both comments.. will fix it :)

Comment: I've edited my answer

Comment: Are you sure this is using the correct timezone (UTC+1)?

Comment: Yes :) it prints the current swatch time, I pushed the current hours in UTC and Incremented it (mod 24).

Comment: The “tio.run” output I was looking at was outdated and just so happened to be exactly an hour behind! Clicking the big ▶️ button re-ran it and I see your code is correct, sorry!

Comment: `1440` can be compressed to `Ž5¦` ([see section *How to compress large integers?* in this 05AB1E tip of mine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210)). As for the `Dg3s-Å0š˜J`, this can be golfed to `₄+¦` (add 1000, remove the first character).

Comment: Oh right! cool!

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 98 bytes

```
d=new Date();t=;console.log(Math.floor((360*d.getHours()+60*d.getMinutes()+d.getSeconds())/86.4));
```

Definitely could be optimized, I had some problems with the `Date` object so I'm looking into shorter ways to do that.

Comment: Hmm. You could probably be more efficient by using the UNIX timestamp feature (`Date.prototype.getTime`), instead of summing the hours, minutes and seconds. Also, though I didn't make this clear before, I think the output should be zero-padded.

Answer (score 1):

## Octave, 64 bytes

```
t=gmtime(time);sprintf("%03.f",(mod(++t.hour,24)*60+t.min)/1.44)
```

Uses [veganaiZe's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/85107/42892) `printf` formatting.

I'm having a bit of difficulty with the time that ideone is returning, so here's a sample run with the time struct returned by `gmtime` for reference. I'll look around and see if I can get any of the other online Octave compilers to give me proper time.

```
t =    
  scalar structure containing the fields:
    usec =  528182
    sec =  17
    min =  24
    hour =  21
    mday =  15
    mon =  6
    year =  116
    wday =  5
    yday =  196
    isdst = 0
    zone = UTC

ans = 933
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2.7, <s>131</s> <s>128</s> 121 bytes:

```
from datetime import*;S=lambda f:int(datetime.utcnow().strftime(f));print'%03.0f'%(((S('%H')+1%24)*3600+S('%M')*60)/86.4)
```

A full program that outputs the Swatch Internet Time.

Simply uses Python's built in `datetime` module to first get the `UTC+0` time in hours and minutes using `datetime.utfnow().strftime('%H')` and `datetime.utfnow().strftime('%M')`, respectively. Then, the time is converted into `UTC+1` by adding `1` to the hours and then modding the sum by `24` to ensure the result is in the 24-hour range. Finally, the hour is turned into its equivalent in seconds, which is added to the minute's equivalent in seconds, and the resulting sum is divided by `86.4`, as there are `86.4` seconds or `1 min. 24 sec.` in 1 ".beat", after which,  using string formatting, the quotient is rounded to the nearest integer and padded with zeroes until the length is `3`.

---

However, I am not the one to stop here. In the above solution, I used a more direct method to convert the time to `UTC+1`. However, wanted to add a bit of a bigger challenge for myself and implement this using *only* Python's built in `time` module, which apparently does *not* have any built-in method that I know of to convert local time into `UTC+0` time. So now, without further ado, here is the perfectly working version using *only* the time module, currently standing at **125 bytes**:

```
from time import*;I=lambda g:int(strftime(g));print'%03.0f'%((((I('%H')+1-daylight)%24*3600+timezone)%86400+I('%M')*60)/86.4)
```

This can output the correct Swatch Internet Time for *any and all* time zones, and basically does pretty much everything the same as in the first solution, except this time converts the local time into `UTC+1` by first adding `1` to the hour, and then subtracting `1` if daylight-savings time is currently, locally observed, or `0` otherwise. Then, this difference is modded by `24` to ensure that the result stays within the `24` hour range, after which it is multiplied by `3600` for conversion into seconds. This product is then added to the result from the built-in `timezone` method, which returns the local offset from `UTC+0`. After this, you finally have your hours in `UTC+1`. This then continues on from here as in the first solution.

Comment: Interesting! Though, it shouldn't be necessary to get this from stdin, given Python knows the current time, right?

Comment: @Andrea It is fixed and works perfectly now.

Comment: Hmm, intriguing. Might it be shorter using UNIX time?

Answer (score 1):

## q/k (21 bytes)

```
7h$1e3*(.z.n+0D01)%1D
```

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript, 83 bytes

```
a=(((36e5+(+new Date()))%864e5)/864e2).toFixed(),alert("00".slice(Math.log10(a))+a)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cjam/), 34 bytes

Update: I shouldn't code hungry. My previous answer was shorter, but didn't cast to int or left-pad. These are now fixed, with +8 bytes to left-pad (probably improvable), +1 to int cast, and -2 to optimizations. My old comment no longer applies.

```
r':/~\~)24md60*@~+1.44/i"%03d"e%o;
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/v0jdSr8upk7TyCQ3xcxAy6FO21DPxEQ/U0nVwDhFKVU13/r/fyNjKxNzAA)

Explanation:

```
r                   read input
 ':/                split on :
    ~               unwrap array
     \~             evaluate hour to numbers
       )            increment hour
        24md        modulo 24
            60*     multiply by 60
               @~   switch to minute and eval to num
+                   add hour*60 and minute
 1.44/              divide by 1.44 to get SIT
      i             cast to int
       "%03d"e%     format as 3 leading 0s
               o;   output and discard spare 0 from modulo
```

Comment: I suppose the first three digits are correct, so maybe it's a valid entry in that way (I never said a newline was required…) but it's not supposed to have a decimal point or any fractional digits.

Comment: Oops, I missed that no decimal requirement. I have other optimizations I thought of in the last half-hour, so I'll just add a cast to int along with those.

Comment: @Andrea I missed the leading 0s requirement, so that's fixed as well. There may be a better way but I'm not very familiar with that part of CJam.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <sup><s>27 23 19</s></sup>  15 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
Kj z86400 s t3n
```

[Test it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=S2ogejg2NDAwIHMgdDNu)

Javascript port.

I hope I've done it correctly.

-4 bytes from Shaggy.

-4 more bytes from Shaggy.

-4 more more bytes from Shaggy.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I've understood the challenge but this definitely isn't right; you need a space before the `/` and the `t2,3` should be at the end, with a space before it, giving `Kj +36e5 /864e5%1+"0000" t2,3`. And, from there, you can get down to 23 bytes with `36e5+Kj)/864e5%1 x4 ¤¯3`. When I figure the challenge out, I'll see if any more can be saved.

Comment: OK, think I've figured it out and you should be able to get down to at least 21 bytes by: claiming locale dependency (i.e., a UTC+1 timezone), getting the current hour, multiplying by 60, adding the minutes, floor dividing by 1.44, converting to a string and then left padding with `0`s.

Comment: Oh, and welcome to Japt :)

Comment: Actually, feck that, just knock the first 5 bytes off the current version for 18 bytes. Dunno why I was trying to overcomplicate it!

Comment: @Shaggy wait, knocking that off is to claim locale dependency, correct?

Comment: Yup. [padding to 15]

Comment: Note to self: Atleast look at the tutorial before using a language.

Comment: 16: `K/864e5%1 x4 ¤¯3`

Comment: 15: `Kj z86400 s t3n`

Comment: 14: `K°z86400 s t3n` - think that's as good as it's gonna get.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 64 bytes

```python
import time
t=time.gmtime()
print(int(-~t[3]%24/.024+t[4]/1.44))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEkMzeVq8QWROml54IoDU2ugqLMvBINENatK4k2jlU1MtHXMzAy0S6JNonVN9QzMdHU/P8fAA)

Comment: This seems to be rounded differently than PHP's `date("B");` but I guess it's close enough? (I don't know what the PHP code does, I'm guessing this is a ceil versus floor difference, or your constants aren't precise enough)

Comment: @Andrea the difference is probably that I'm using only the hour and minute specifiers, whereas I'm guessing the php implementation uses a more precise value. My approach is rounded down to the minute, as per all the test cases.

Comment: Fair enough! Swatch Internet Time is not very precise so I won't be pedantic over precision if it's only off by ±1.

Answer (score 0):

## C#, 112 bytes

```
class P{static void M(){System.Console.Write((int)((DateTime.UtcNow.TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds%86400+3600)/86.4));}}
```

---

## C#, 68 bytes

```
()=>(int)((DateTime.UtcNow.TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds%86400+3600)/86.4);
```

A simple port of @veganaiZe's code. Thanks to him :)

[Try it online!](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7yE0Lz)

Comment: Is this a "complete and runnable program"? I don't know much C#, but this looks like a lambda than a full program.

Comment: @YakovLipkovich Lambda are allowed on PPCG. Well I saw that here, in this specific question, they aren't. I asked why.

Comment: Since this adds `3600` *after* doing the modulo, won't it return the wrong result after 23:00 UTC?

Comment: @Andrea Maybe indeed. Did you try it after 23h?

Comment: @aloisdg I haven't tried your code yet, but it should be clear this will happen without running it.

Answer (score 0):

### Common Lisp (Lispworks), 144 bytes

```
(defun f(s)(let*((d(split-sequence":"s))(h(parse-integer(first d)))(m(parse-integer(second d))))(round(/(+(*(mod(1+ h) 24)3600)(* m 60))86.4))))
```

ungolfed:

```
    (defun f (s)
      (let* ((d (split-sequence ":" s))
             (h (parse-integer (first d)))
             (m (parse-integer (second d))))
        (round
         (/
          (+
           (*
            (mod (1+ h) 24)
            3600)
           (* m 60))
          86.4))))
```

usage:

```
CL-USER 2759 > (f "23:47")
33
-0.36111111111111427
```