# A decimal-based unit of time

Tags: code-golf, math

#### Background

In 1960, the [11th General Conference on Weights and Measures](https://physics.nist.gov/cuu/Units/international.html#:%7E:text=The%20International%20System%20of%20Units,G%C3%A9n%C3%A9rale%20des%20Poids%20et%20Mesures) defined the Système International d'Unités (SI) Units which scientists still use today.

The metre and the kilogram became standard units in that conference. These were based on powers of 10 (10, 100, 1000, etc.).

For example:

- there are *100* centimetres in one meter
- there are *1000* meters in one kilometer
- there are *1000* grams in one kilogram

#### Time units

That conference also established the second as the standard unit for time. Now, this is interesting, because this is not based on powers of 10.

- There are *60* seconds in one minute
- There are *60* minutes in one hour
- There are *24* hours in one day

So let's make our own!

In our system, we will have:

- *100* seconds in one minute
- *100* minutes in one hour
- *10* hours in one day

#### Your task

Given an input of a time (in 24-hour time), convert it to our system (10-hour).

**Example:**

Input: `12:34:56`

First, convert this to a number of seconds:

`(12 * 60 * 60) + (34 * 60) + 56 = 45296`

We have 100,000 seconds in our system, and in the normal system there are 86,400. We need to adjust for that:

`45296 / 86400 * 100000 = 52425.9259259259`

We round this to 52426. Note: this must be rounded.

Now, convert back to hours, minutes and seconds. This is easy because our 10-100-100 system lets us just place the colons in: `5:24:26`. This is our final answer.

**Note: you do not need to insert the colons.**

#### Test cases

You can input and output in any format you want, including just an integer as the output format.

Here are some test cases:

```
Input     Output
12:34:56  5:24:26
00:00:00  0:00:00*
23:59:59  9:99:99
11:11:11  4:66:10
15:25:35  6:42:77
01:02:03  0:43:09*
```

<sup>*</sup> In these ones, you do not have to fill the minutes and seconds up to two places: i.e., you may output `0:0:0` and `0:43:9`.

**This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins!**

Comment: [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/25199/114446)

Comment: Historical aside: this decimal time system was [officially adopted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_time#France) in France for part of 1794 and 1795.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/85084/calculate-swatch-internet-time)

Comment: In other words, Implement [Swatch Internet Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swatch_Internet_Time) to 1/100th of a Beat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>10</s> 9 bytes

No 05AB1E yet? Let's fix that!

This is a direct port of hakr14's [canvas answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/252955/111498).

```
60βƵOƵ7/*ò
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fzODcpmNb/Y9tNdfXOrzp//9oQ1MdI1MdY9NYAA)

```
60βƵOƵ7/*ò
60β           Convert input from base 60
   ƵOƵ7/      Push 125/108
        *     Multiply input and 125/108
         ò    Round
```

Thanks to @TheThonnu for this answer:

```
60β.864/ò
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fzODcJj0LMxP9w5v@/482NNUxMtUxNo0FAA)

```
60β.864/ò
60β          Convert input from base 60
   .864      Push .864 (108/125)
       /     Divide input by 108/125
        ò    Round
```

Comment: [9 bytes](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fzODcJj0LMxP9w5v@/482NNUxMtUxNo0FAA "05AB1E – Try It Online")

Comment: @TheThonnu So simple, why didn't i think of that? Nicely done, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

## JavaScript (ES6), 33 bytes

Expects `(h,m,s)` and returns an integer.

```javascript
(h,m,s)=>(h*60+m+s/60)*625/9+.5|0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY/LCoMwFET3/Yq7NJqadyQX7L@I1T5QU5rSVf89jYQuGpizOwwz9@E9hPF5e7yOmz9Pce5jdaUrDaQ/Vdfa8mZtArOc1FYa5prWfHgc/Rb8MrWLv1RzJSQFpSkYSwgwBgalRmkP/xZwCplsceR7Ckuq1ON2suXQ7SksIShksqXRWhRllzAUZEKZbFnUEruu3JV6ID0A9dulFXIXvw)

#### How?

By converting to minutes instead of seconds, the final ratio is:

$$\frac{60\times 100000}{86400}=\frac{625}{9}$$

This is one byte shorter than:

```javascript
(h,m,s)=>(h*3600+m*60+s)/.864+.5|0
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 11 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ḅ60÷.864+.Ḟ
```

A monadic Link that accepts a list of non-negative integers, `[h, m, s]`, and yields a non-negative integer.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjlYzg8Pb9SzMTLT1Hu6Y9////2hDIx1jEx1Ts1gA)** Or see the [test-suite](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjlYzg8Pb9SzMTLT1Hu6Y9//opIc7Z@gcbs961DBHwdZO4VHDXM3I//@jow2NdIxNdEzNYrl0og10gBDEMDLWMbUEIhDb0FAHjMBsUx0jUx1jUzBbB6gTpssQwjCEaDeEmBMLAA).

#### How?

```
ḅ60÷.864+.Ḟ - Link: list of non-negative integers, T = [h, m, s]:
ḅ60         - convert T from base sixty -> 3600*h+60*m+s = seconds
    .864    - 0.864 (seconds per "second")
   ÷        - (seconds) divide (0.864) -> "deconds"
         .  - a half
        +   - (deconds) add (a half)
          Ḟ - floor to nearest integer
```

Comment: You need to add `.432` before dividing to round correctly (`.5` only works after you divide).

Comment: Oops, that was dumb! Thanks @Neil

Answer (score 4):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 39 bytes

Port of `@Arnauld`'s answer, expects an input of `h, m, s` and returns an integer.

```python
lambda h,m,s:round((h*60+m+s/60)*625/9)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY31XMSc5NSEhUydHJ1iq2K8kvzUjQ0MrTMDLRztYv1zQw0tcyMTPUtNaHKU9LyiyBqFTLzFKKjDY10jE10TM1idRSiDQx0wAjENjLWMbUEIhDb0FAHjMBsUx0jUx1jUzBbB6g5NtaKS6GgKDOvRCNNA2ywJtSuBQsgNAA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 35 bytes

```factor
[ 60 * rot 60 / + + 625/9 * round ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY/BDoIwEETvfMV41URKa0nQDzBevBhPhgOpJRKkxXZ7MIRvx2LQ3clmd/L2MHWlyLrpejmdj3u02hn9RFfR4zu2dTCKGms8eqeJ3r1rDMHrV9BGaY9DkgwJYg2QOcQOGccYz1VklDV3j64xgSL5sMH5BWVs0fj7LWZx8TeybNHPEBJcIpN/gwkwDjYTYzLdkDOs4SzNS4pN7JzLtPiawdxRRqZunCeBcg7TW69jxh6eKtVupw8)

Expects `seconds minutes hours` as integers. Port of Arnauld's [JavaScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/252949/97916).

```
      ! 56 34 12
60    ! 56 34 12 60
*     ! 56 34 720
rot   ! 34 720 56
60    ! 34 720 56 60
/     ! 34 720 14/15
+     ! 34 720+14/15
+     ! 754+14/15
625/9 ! 754+14/15 69+4/9
*     ! 52425+25/27
round ! 52426
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 65 bytes

```python
h,m,s=map(int,input().split())
print(round((h*3600+m*60+s)/.864))
```

Takes input as `HH mm ss` and outputs as `Hmmss`

-3 thanks to Jonathan Allan

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Dcg5DoAgEADA3ldQ7gJBFCQ2PsbEAhKBDUfh65FqkqGv@ZzMGF5GWa94E4TUZEjUG6Cq9IYpLlRmQ8k9PQCeG6e1iNxpUXFVp7OIY2w7M5Yd7gc)

Comment: `/.864` saves three bytes.

Answer (score 3):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), 13 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
‾-┴‾n‾]÷×１½＋ｕ
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXUyMDNFLSV1MjUzNCV1MjAzRW4ldTIwM0UlNUQlRjclRDcldUZGMTElQkQldUZGMEIldUZGNTU_,i=JTVCMTIlMkMzNCUyQzU2JTVE,v=8)

###### Explanation:

```
‾-┴‾n‾]÷×1½+u | Full code (converted to half-width)
--------------+------------------------------------
‾-┴           | Convert input from base 60
   ‾n‾]÷      | Push 125/108
        ×     | Multiply
         1½+  | Add .5
            u | Floor
```

Answer (score 3):

## [C (GCC)](https://gcc.gnu.org), <s>73</s> 68 bytes

*-5 bytes thanks to [@Neil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/17602/neil)*

```
f(char*x){return((atoi(x)*3600+atoi(x+3)*60+atoi(x+6))*125+54)/108;}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700OT49OXnBgqWlJWm6Fjdd0jSSMxKLtCo0q4tSS0qL8jQ0EkvyMzUqNLWMzQwMtCEcbWNNLTM4x0xTU8vQyFTb1ERT39DAwroWapZ6bmJmnoZmNRdnQVFmXkmahpJqipIOkDI0sjI2sTI1U9LUtOaq5YIohzkBAA)

Comment: [41 bytes](https://tio.run/##BcFBCoAgEADAcz4jCHZ1I7WUQHpMGKYHJapb@Hab8ePpfWsBImV68IsbQOSzlVJkbqV4kCtthFlwUnJ1teU9FcCPddedyhugH46eAihN80LGIjpW2w8)

Comment: or [36 bytes](https://tio.run/##BcFbCoAgEADA7zxGEOzm9k4hosOEYQYZkUEf4dXbZkyxGsNswZGngK@bwOW6ll6GStcl5rpV1SBLNUb283YAviI5r@24LaTZkpKFpqWuJ6URRxH5M3af18DF8wM) based on Arnauld's

Comment: @jdt you can post it as a new answer if you want, it's basically a new solution (although ported from another language)

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 13 bytes

```
Ｉ⌊⊘⊕∕↨⁶⁰Ａ·⁴³²
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcaxCoMwEADQX8l4gVhStS5uWqTZ3MXhiAcGYiIx5vevpW96dsdkI3rmObmQYcQrw@RjTPBBX2gDE2yig0L@/e2K2wgGvAg6rYQJ551BSiX0o21q@dczL8uzVqJplXh168pV8V8) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes input as a list. Explanation:

```
       Ａ        Input array
     ↨          Converted from base
      ⁶⁰        Literal integer `60`
    ∕           Divided by
         ·⁴³²   Literal number `0.432`
   ⊕            Incremented
  ⊘             Halved
 ⌊              Floor
Ｉ               Cast to string
                Implicitly print
```

26 bytes for string I/O:

```
✂⪫⪪﹪%06.0f∕↨⁶⁰Ｉ⪪Ｓ:·⁸⁶⁴¦²:¹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYxRC8IgFEb/igjBFWy4tSTsbeulIAj8BeKsLoiO7W5/3xbs6TscDp//uslnF0t5TZgIbEQf4JExgR0jEjzzsMQM/KB0pd5cshuuOATo3BxAK8l6N9Pe3tO4kKXt6ANCMm64ENuq6qLbPzS7lKwW4lpK3ZhTa866HNf4Aw) Link is to verbose version of code.

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 19 bytes

```
0.864<.@%~0.5+60#.]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYvBCkBAFEX3vuJGkvB6M@NNiFLKysreSiQbf@DXh5Kpcxenzj1dSMmOrkGCHIzmXUEY5ml0TJUtW@rjm0kyyxEtLg0QbOtxYYfSMCXE/s788bs2kPrF9@rDu0ALjPi/AmuwcQ8)

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 11 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
ì60 /.864 r
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=7DYwIC8uODY0IHI&footer=7Ew&input=WzEyIDM0IDU2XQ)

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 12 bytes

```
/hyiQ60y.864
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/Xz@jMjPQzKBSz8LM5P//aEMjHWMTHVOzWAA) Input takes a list `[hours, minutes, seconds]`, and outputs an integer.

**Explanation:**

```
/hyiQ60y.864 # whole program

    Q        # take the input
   i 60      # and convert it from base 60 to decimal
  y          # double it
 h           # increment it
/            # then integer divide it by
       y.864 # 0.864 doubled (which is 1.728)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 40 bytes

```
\d+
$*
+`1:
:60$*
1
125$*
::
54$*
1{108}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HccxCoRAEETRvM6xgmjS1WOL1gW8hIGCBiYbLJuJZx9H4cGv@u3/47vmqp6WPG8tPg3ahYJ6K5OgR6mE6J5/0oYrZ7pSp@hhphc8KcYCpF5gyEMpYJS5LN0) Link includes test cases. Explanation: Port of my golf to @matteo_c's answer.

```
\d+
$*
```

Convert the hours, minutes and seconds to unary.

```
+`1:
:60$*
```

Convert from base 60, by multiplying each `1` by 60 as it passes a `:` on its way to being a number of seconds.

```
1
125$*
```

Multiply by 125.

```
::
54$*
```

Add 54.

```
1{108}
```

Integer divide by 108 and convert to decimal.

Answer (score 2):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 15 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
╚*j╟*++╔/☼*∞)i½
```

Inputs as three loose floats, output as a single integer.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///R1FlaWY@mztfS1n40dYr@oxl7tB51zNPMPLT3/39DIz0DBWMTIGFqpmfAZWAAZMEJLiNjkIQllOAyNASy4ASXoSmQZQQijE1BekESBiDzDIDaAA)

**Explanation:**

Even though MathGolf has single-byte constants for `60`, `3600`, `86400`, and `100000`, it's still pretty long because it's missing base-conversion and round builtins, so those have to be done by manually.

```python
╚*               # Multiply the first (implicit) input by 3600
  j              # Get the second input-float
   ╟*            # Multiply it by 60
     +           # Add the two together
      +          # Also add the third (implicit) input-float
       ╔/        # Divide this by 86400
         ☼*      # Multiply it by 100000
           ∞)i½  # Round it:
           ∞     #  Double this float
            )    #  Increase it by 1
             i   #  Truncate it to an integer
              ½  #  Integer-divide it by 2
                 # (after which the entire stack is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$ 11 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 9.05 bytes

```
aKAd.864/Zv
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuharE70dU_QszEz0o8ogIlCJBauiDU11jEx1jE1jISIA) or [verify all test cases](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wVbPascKR6XqiloFBYWYEl07BaUon4qlpSVpuhZrE70dUxIjDA0s9LWiyiBii6K8IYyl0UopSrE33aMNjXQUjE10FEzNYrmiDXQUQAjIMjIGClmCMJBjaKijAMEgjqmOghEQG5uCOEA2kBkLMRQA)

##### Explanation

```python
aKAd.864/Zv  # Implicit input
aKAd         # Convert from a list of digits in base-60
    .864/    # Divide by .864
         Zv  # Round to the nearest integer
             # Implicit output
```